# Why git can't remember my passphrase under Windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cmd

I have just start using git and i can't get it to remember my passphrase I'm using cmd.exe elevated and my git host is github and i have create a ssh key like that guide on github

but i still get

```
*\subnus.mvc>git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Subnus/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Comment: I haven't used msysgit myself, but the [pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) authentication agent *may* be helpful.

Comment: I tried everything and then I found [this](http://www.programmoria.com/2012/02/saving-tortoisegit-password.html) which worked.

Comment: Windows 10 ships with OpenSSH for some time now. Enable the ssh-agent service, use ssh-add to add your key to the ssh store, and set `GIT_SSH` in your environment (if necessary) and git/ssh will remember your passphrase via ssh-agent. See my answer below for more detailed instructions.

Comment: 2019, just installed git on windows 10 and git asks for the password _once_, and remembers it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You might not be using OpenSSL.

Comment: I'm not changing anything so maybe I'm using windows SSH.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

I realize that this question is coming up on two years old, but I had the same issue and several answers here did not completely answer the question for me. Here are three step-by-step solutions, depending on whether you use TortoiseGit in addition to msysgit or not.

**First solution** Assumes Windows, msysgit, and PuTTY.

1. Install msysgit and PuTTY as instructed.
2. (Optional) Add PuTTY to your path. *(If you do not do this, then any references to PuTTY commands below must be prefixed with the full path to the appropriate executable.)*
3. If you have not done so already, then generate a key hash as instructed at GitHub or as instructed by your Git host.
4. Again, if you have not already done so, convert your key for use with PuTTY's pageant.exe using **puttygen.exe**. Instructions are in PuTTY's documentation, in [this helpful guide](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/putty-rsa-dsa-keys/), and several other places in cyberspace.
5. Run PuTTY's **pageant.exe**, open your .ppk file ("Add Key"), and provide your passphrase for your key.
6. Access Windows' environment variables dialog (Right-click on "Computer", Click on "Properties", Click on "Advanced system settings" or the "Advanced" tab, click on "Environment Variables").  Add the following environment variable:

   GIT_SSH=C:\full\path\to\plink.exe

   Replace "C:\full\path\to" with the full installation path to PuTTY, where plink.exe is found. It is probably best to add it to the "User variables" section. Also, make sure that the path you use to plink.exe matches the path you use for Pageant (pageant.exe). In some cases, you may have several installations of PuTTY because it might be installed along with other applications. Using plink.exe from one installation and pageant.exe from another will likely cause you trouble.
7. Open a command prompt.
8. If you are trying to connect to a git repository hosted at Github.com then run the following command:

   plink.exe git@github.com

   If the git repository you are trying to connect to is hosted somewhere else, then replace *git@github.com* with an appropriate user name and URL. (Assuming Github) You should be informed that the server's host key is not cached, and asked if you trust it. Answer with a **y**. This will add the server's host key to PuTTY's list of known hosts. Without this step, git commands will not work properly. After hitting enter, Github informs you that Github does not provide shell access. That's fine...we don't need it. (If you are connecting to some other host, and it gives you shell access, it is probably best to terminate the link without doing anything else.)
9. All done!  Git commands should now work from the command line. You may want to have pageant.exe [load your .ppk file automatically at boot time](http://blog.shvetsov.com/2010/03/making-pageant-automatically-load-keys.html), depending on how often you'll be needing it.

**Second solution** Assumes Windows, msysgit, and TortoiseGit.

TortoiseGit comes with PuTTY executables and a specially modified version of plink (called TortoisePlink.exe) that will make things easier.

1. Install msysgit and TortoiseGit as instructed.
2. If you have not done so already, then generate a key hash as instructed at GitHub or as instructed by your Git host.
3. Again, if you have not already done so, convert your key for use with TortoiseGit's pageant.exe using TortoiseGit's **puttygen.exe**. Instructions are in PuTTY's documentation, in the helpful guide linked to in the first solution, and in several other places in cyberspace.
4. Run TortoiseGit's **pageant.exe**, open your .ppk file ("Add Key") and provide your passphrase for your key.
5. Access Windows' environment variables dialog (Right-click on "Computer", Click on "Properties", Click on "Advanced system settings" or the "Advanced" tab, click on "Environment Variables").  Add the following environment variable:

   GIT_SSH=C:\full\path\to\TortoisePlink.exe

   Replace "C:\full\path\to" with the full installation path to TortoiseGit, where TortoisePlink.exe is found. It is probably best to add it to the "User variables" section.  Also, make sure that the path you use to TortoisePlink.exe matches the path you use for Pageant (pageant.exe). In some cases, you may have several installations of PuTTY because it might be installed along with other applications. Using TortoisePlink.exe from the TortoiseGit installation and pageant.exe from another installation of a different application (or from a standalone PuTTY installation) will likely cause you trouble.
6. All done!  Git commands should now work from the command line. The first time you try to connect to your git repository you will probably be informed that the server's host key is not cached, and asks if you trust the server. Click on "Yes". (This is TortoisePlink.exe in action.)

   You may want to have pageant.exe [load your .ppk file automatically at boot time](http://blog.shvetsov.com/2010/03/making-pageant-automatically-load-keys.html), depending on how often you'll be needing it.

**Third solution** Assumes Windows, msysgit, and the native command prompt.

1. Install msysgit
2. Make sure to allow git to be used on the MS-DOS command prompt
3. Run `start-ssh-agent`
4. Enter SSH passphrases
5. All done! Git commands should now work in the native command prompt.

Comment: If you have both GitExtensions and TortoiseGit, each of which has its own version of putty, make sure you set the **GIT_SSH** environment variable to the path of the plink for the pageant you're actually using.

Comment: Just in case someone else runs into this stupid error: make sure you're using the SSH remote URL format (git@host:accountname/reponame.git) not the HTTPS URL otherwise it'll keep on asking for that password...

Comment: When I run plink.exe git@github.com, I get "FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection"

Comment: The latest TortoiseGIT lets you set the Putty key from Settings > Git > Remote > origin > Putty Key. It still requires converting to special Putty format and git@host format URL.

Comment: Somehow the shell didn't take the GIT_SSH variable if it contained spaces, so I used: ln -s /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/PuTTY/plink.exe /bin/plink

Comment: @Adder That's one way to do it, I suppose. You might want to investigate using quoted strings in environment variables for future similar situations you might encounter. A bit easier than linking.

Comment: Note: method three has been [upstreamed into msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/cmd/start-ssh-agent.cmd) so you can just type `start-ssh-agent` in the command line to get it to save your SSH passphrase.

Comment: The `start-ssh-agent` option is really awesome and simple! Love it! It's entirely inexplicable to me that this is not on [the relevant Github documentation page](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/)!?

Comment: Oddly, when I use the HTTPS url I get no password prompt. without it I do.

Comment: Third solution works only until command prompt is closed and only for that command prompt - all other CMDs still ask for a passphrase. Also all the other clients (VS, VS Code) fail to communicate with remote git.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it seems like using `start-ssh-agent` transforms my Powershell instance into a vanilla CMD instance.

Answer (score 244):

*Every time I set up a new desktop I forget these instructions, so I'm adding another answer here since I stumble across it equally often!*

---

### Quick Steps for Impatient Users Like Me

1. Enable the `OpenSSH Authentication Agent` service and make it start automatically.

   - **Update**
   - With the latest Windows update `Version 10.0.19042.867` I had to re-do this step!
2. Add your SSH key to the agent with `ssh-add` on the command line.
3. Test git integration, if it still asks for your passphrase, continue on.
4. Add the environment variable `$ENV:GIT_SSH=C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` to your session, or permanently to your user environment.

---

### Detailed Steps: Overview

Windows has been [shipping with OpenSSH for some time now.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/openssh-in-windows-10/) It includes all the necessary bits for ssh to work alongside Git, but it still seems to need some TLC before it works 100% seamlessly. Here's the steps I've been following with success as of Windows ver 10.0.18362.449 (you can see your Windows 10 version by opening a cmd.exe shell and typing `ver`).

*I assume here that you already have your SSH key setup, and is located at `~/.ssh/id_rsa`*

#### Enable the ssh-agent service on your Windows 10 box.

1. Start-> Type 'Services' and click on the Services App that appears.
2. Find the `OpenSSH Authentication Agent` service in the list.
3. Right-click on the `OpenSSH Authentication Agent` service, and choose 'Properties'.
4. Change the `Startup type:` to `Automatic`.
5. Click the `Start` button to change the service status to `Running`.
6. Dismiss the dialog by clicking `OK`, and close the Services app.

#### Add your key to the `ssh-agent`

1. Open your shell of preference *(I'll use Windows Powershell in this example, applies to Powershell Core too)*.
2. Add your SSH key to the `ssh-agent`: `ssh-add` *(you can add the path to your key as the first argument if it differs from the default)*.
3. Enter your passphrase if/when prompted to do so.

#### Try Git + SSH

1. Open your shell *(again, I'm using Powershell)* and clone a repo. `git clone git@github.com:octocat/Spoon-Knife`
2. **If you see this prompt, continue on to the next section:**

```
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/your_user_name/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

#### Set your `GIT_SSH` Environment Variable

In any session you can simply set this environment variable and the prompt for your passphrase will stop coming up and ssh will use the `ssh-agent` on your behalf. Alternatively, you can set your passphrase into your user's environment permanently.

**To set `GIT_SSH` in the current shell only:**

1. Open your shell of preference. *(Powershell for me)*
2. Set the environment variable GIT_SSH to the appropriate `ssh.exe`: `$Env:GIT_SSH=$((Get-Command -Name ssh).Source)`
3. Retry the steps in **Try Git + SSH** above.

**To set `GIT_SSH` permanently**

1. Open File Explorer. Start-> type 'File Explorer' and click on it in the list.
2. Right-click 'This PC' and click on 'Properties'.
3. Click on 'Advanced system settings'.
4. Click the 'Environment Variables...' button.
5. Under 'User variables for your_user_name' click New...
6. Set `Variable name:` field to GIT_SSH
7. Set the `Variable value:` field to path-to-ssh.exe (typically `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`).
8. Click OK to dismiss the New User Variable dialog.
9. Click OK to dismiss the Environment Variables dialog.
10. Retry the steps in **Try Git + SSH** above.

---

*Note that this is likely going to change with new steps/procedures as Windows 10 progresses and as I learn more. I will attempt to keep this updated, I look forward to feedback in the comments.*

Comment: This is the most complete answer as of 1/31/2020, at least for Windows. There's no need to install PUTTY or anything.

Comment: Agreed. It appears that built-in support is finally here.

Comment: Legend! This solved my problem. Been looking for a solution for a while, trying different things and this is hands down the most complete awnser to this problem

Comment: Thank you for a nice answer and one that saved me most likely a few hours of messing around. +1

Comment: Thanks for that! The only thing I was missing was the environment variable. I couldn't figure out why it was working, and I could ssh-add without error, and the agent was running, but it wouldn't remember my credentials!

Comment: This helped, but I ended up with 2 `ssh.exe` versions and 2 ssh agents: One from `msysgit` and one from windows. Setting `GIT_SSH` was not enough, I had to remove `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` to force git for windows to use the windows version of `ssh`, and thus the correct agent.

Comment: @Willem is it possible that you had the path to the offending `ssh.exe` in your `PATH` environment variable, listed before the system `ssh` PATH? Whichever one is listed first will get called.

Comment: Yes it is, but the offending `ssh.exe` is the one from `msysgit` itself, which when using git bash is always automatically put as the first item.

Comment: Ah understood @Willem, my post is focused at use of Git within the Powershell/cmd.exe/Windows Shell though and not Git-Bash. Git-Bash is a different setup and some of the other answers on this page will likely be of more use to you for that scenario (and as far as I can tell, they aren't mutually exclusive solutions either). Good luck!

Comment: If you're using git in Powershell, in March 2021, this is the answer you need. SSH support has been native in Windows for a while now.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio then because the included git.exe is 32-bit you need to create a **directory junction** pointing to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` and set GIT_SSH environment variable to `C:\PathToJunction\ssh.exe`. Otherwise VS internal git.exe will fail to locate ssh.exe because a 32-bit executable cannot directly access System32 on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Saul! For 3rd party tools such as Visual Studio and others there will likely always be edge cases that won't work with the _base setup_ discussed in this post. There are specific posts that can help these edge cases (and are likely better than this more generic one), for instance, I found this for VS2017: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42773636/895739. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect tutorial, thank you very much! For those who use a terminal inside their IDE: after going through this step-by-step, you may need to restart your IDE! I was working in a VSCode project and used that terminal for the GIT commands, and after the tutorial it still asked for a passphrase. After closing and reopening VSCode, this was gone :)

Comment: Setting the environment variable GIT_SSH is a must. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the correct answer! You may need to close and reopen the terminal in Windows to activate the new env variable.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still am asked for the passphrase.

Comment: @AgentFire could you please provide further details? What is on your PATH? What did you set into the GIT_SSH variable? Did you use the instructions for "Current shell" or "Permanenty" above? (If you used "Current Shell" did you open another window?). I would love to know more so I can update the post with better/more information!

Comment: @d3r3kk I have used the advanced system settings menu to set the `GIT_SSH` var **permanently** (for the current user) to `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`.

Comment: Interesting. Verify that the OpenSSH service is set up properly, use `ssh-add -l` (l for List), to verify your ssh key registered. Also use `where ssh` (cmd.exe) or `Get-Command ssh` (powershell) to verify where your system thinks Git is installed via PATH. If that doesn't match, you may need to alter your PATH variable - although that _shouldn't_ matter, but maybe it does. Let us know how it works out.

Comment: Thank you, after setting GIT_SSH env, I find that this works correctly under both powershell and git-bash.  Would be good if someone could clarify whether this also works under WSL, or what steps are appropriate.

Comment: WSL will use the git environment defined within the distro of Linux that you choose. That's kind of out of scope for this post, but there is literally avalanches of data on how to set that [up across the Internet.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=setting+up+git+with+ssh+in+debian&t=h_&ia=web). You _can_ share keys between WSL and Windows though, if that makes your life easier!

Comment: I have tried everything, but only after applying the 4th step (Add the environment variable $ENV:GIT_SSH=C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe to your session, or permanently to your user environment.), it worked. Thank you!

Comment: This is the most accurate answer as of 2023. Just wanted to add a few powershell commands to: change the startup mode of the Agent to Automatic => Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic; to persist the environment variable: [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('GIT_SSH', $((Get-Command -Name ssh).Source), 'User')

Comment: Thanks for this! Just what I was looking for.
Hope Microsoft makes this all more manageable in the future. Maybe extend Certificate Manager, or create something similar, for managing our well-secured SSH keys.

Comment: @Saul: Can you maybe explain your comment with the directory junctions a bit more? 
How can I create one? I got it running outside of VSCode but in the internal editor, the environment variable does not seem to get found (e.g. `$Env:GIT_SSH` does not print anything at all)

Comment: @BenediktBöhm You can create one with [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) using "/j" switch. The junction to `System32\OpenSSH` can be created under any directory. Once it's there then assign GIT_SSH environment variable as full path of junction slash ssh.exe.

Answer (score 56):

In case you are using ***Git bash*** under ***Windows*** you can perform the following:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/*_rsa
```

it will ask for pass phrase in the second command, and that's it. Each additional action you will need to do (which once required pass phrase) won't ask you for the pass phrase (see an example in the screen shot below):

[image: adding pass phrase in Git bash on Windows]

Comment: This also works in the Ubuntu subsystem in Windows 10.

Comment: note that if your keypair is located elsewhere you can replace ~/.ssh/*_rsa with the path of the *.pem file

Comment: error for 2nd command: No such file or directory

Comment: This will only work for the current session. If you close Git bash, you'll have to enter the passphrase again.

Answer (score 23):

For anybody needing more detailed instructions, see this page:
https://docs.github.com/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases

Comment: Exactly what I needed for using the `msysgit` shell.

Comment: Worked for me when using the Git Bash Desktop App. I used `notepad ~/.profile` and copy pasted the content from that link, restarted the Git Bash, entered my password, profited...

Comment: I followed "Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows" section  (using git 2.x on Win 10) but it still asked me for password all the time. Following first solution (putty) from accepted answer fixed this for me.

Comment: I was able to get it so the passphrase is only prompted for once after a boot using the script at [Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows). I did find, however, it didn't work when I added it add it to either `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`. I needed to add it to `~/.bash_profile` for it to get picked up and used by Git Bash on Windows. I now see @alexander-goncharov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49638778/1703887) below says this.

Answer (score 13):

One extra solution 5 years, 8 months and 6 days after the question was posted wouldn't be a bad idea so here goes.

**NOTE:** Assumes you are using a windows computer.

1. Download the [git-credential-winstore](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows).
2. Run it! If you have GIT in your `PATH` environment variable, it should just work. If you don't, run `git-credential-winstore -i C:\Path\To\Git.exe`.

The next time you attempt to commit to a repository, you'll be prompted to enter your credentials. That should be it. You will not be asked for your credentials any longer until you change your password.

---

Just for your knowledge... Your credentials are stored in the Windows Credential Store

> **Where are you storing my credentials?**
>
> This app just uses the existing Windows Credential Store to hold your credentials. You can see the stored credentials by going to Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager and choosing "Windows Credentials". The entries starting "git:" are from git-credential-winstore.

Comment: This solution appears to not work with SSH repos, only HTTPS.  /angryface

Answer (score 10):

Let's assume you'd like to use a pure **Git Bash** only solution without using TortoiseGit or PuTTY. Also, you don't want to store your passphrases permanently as it's almost the same as if you would've generated your SSH key without a passphrase in the first place. But you still want to use some caching.

For caching purposes `ssh-agent` process is used, which is included with the Git Bash distribution. This process isn't started by default, so it needs to be launched first. For any SSH keys to be cached they should be added to this process with `ssh-add` command which will prompt you for a key's passphrase and store it in memory.

Drawbacks of other solutions:

- Auto-launching `ssh-agent` like in [GitHub's](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows) article asks for a passphrase right from the start when you launch Git Bash, regardless of whether you'll need to use your SSH key this session or not. If you're working with your local repo today you'll probably want to provide a passphrase only when really needed (e.g. when interacting with a remote repo).
- If you launch your `ssh-agent` like in [GitLab's](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths) article with `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` you're probably tired of typing that in each time. Chances are, eventually, you've added those two lines to your `.bashrc` config to auto-launch. Downsides are the same as above plus an extra one: each time you launch a new Git Bash terminal you'll get an extra ssh-agent process (GitHub's bash script checks if that process has already started).
- Like the two above but especially so when you have separate SSH keys for different hosts, e.g. one for GitHub and another one for GitLab, so providing them all at once is annoying and inconvenient.

So this solution is for those who wonder how to make Git Bash ask for a passphrase only once per Windows session and only when really needed. It resembles the behavior of passphrases management with GnuPG commits [auto-signing](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/signing-commits) using [`default-cache-ttl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369506/3210423).

#### Configuring SSH to ask for passphrases once, when needed, using Git Bash only

1. First, we want to auto-launch the `ssh-agent` when starting a Git Bash shell. We'll use a modified GitHub's [script](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows) for that as it checks whether the process has already started, but we don't want it to `ssh-add` keys right away. This script goes to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` (`~` is your User's home directory like `C:\Users\Username` – run `cd ~` and then `pwd` for the Git Bash to print it out):

   ```sh
   ### Start ssh-agent

   env=~/.ssh/agent.env

   agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

   agent_start () {
       (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")  # use -t here for timeout
       . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

   agent_load_env

   # agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
   agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

   if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
       agent_start
   fi

   unset env
   ```
2. Now edit or create a `~/.ssh/config` file and add an **`AddKeysToAgent`** option for each host stanza you want caching to be turned on (you can also turn it on globally by placing the directive at the beginning of the file before all the host declarations):

   ```sh
   # GitHub.com
   Host github.com
     Preferredauthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github
     AddKeysToAgent yes

   # GitLab.com
   Host gitlab.com
     Preferredauthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_gitlab
     AddKeysToAgent yes
   ```

   > *From ssh config man [page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#AddKeysToAgent):* If this option is set to yes and a key is loaded from a file, the key and its passphrase are added to the agent with the default lifetime, as if by ssh-add(1).

The default maximum lifetime is forever or until the `ssh-agent` process gets killed (either manually from task manager or when your PC is shut down). If you wish to use a finite timeout you can set it with ssh-agent's [`-t`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-agent.1#t) parameter. Change the line in the bash script from the first step above, e.g. for 30 minutes key cache lifetime:

```sh
(umask 077; ssh-agent -t 30m >| "$env")
```

See [here](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5#TIME_FORMATS) for other time format qualifiers.

Answer (score 8):

If you set a password for your key file, you'll always need to type in that password when connecting.  If you create a passwordless key, then you won't have to type it every time, however, anyone with access to your key file can now connect to your github account.

ssh-agent may also work.  Try running that and see if it will remember your passphrase.

Comment: running `ssh-keygen -p` should allow the OP to set no passphrase

Comment: Still prompting for password.

Answer (score 7):

[edit - misread the question, this is an answer to a related problem.  leaving rephrased version for posterity]

My case was that I was trying to push to a repo that was hosted on one of our servers. Whenever I tried to do a push, git would ask me for my password (nb - password, not the passphrase to my private key).

By adding my public key to the authorised keys on the server, I was able to get password-free pushes to that server.  And, because there was no *passphrase* on my private key (which is bad practice btw!) I didn't need to type anything at all in.

Here's the command to add your public key to a server.  It assumes the user `git` is the user on the server.

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh git@GIT_MASTER_IP 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

You could achieve the same thing by logging onto the server, and manually appending your public key to the file at `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Could you convert this into a description usable by someone who doesnt have access to a shell?  E.g. what should we put in authorized_keys using notepad or similar?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `.bashrc` file in the home directory of your user like `C:/Users/youruser`, and put there:

```sh
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

This script executes every time after bash runs. So you will need to enter the password only once, when `git-bash` is started!

Some versions of bash require `.bash_profile` file instead `.bashrc`, so just in case clone `.bashrc`:

```
copy .bashrc .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is several years overdue, but I stumbled across this question trying to find a solution for it, and I found something that suits all levels of expertise, so I thought I'd share.

GitHub provide a very helpful installer that makes everything nice and easy: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: Please note this is caching your GitHub *password*, not a GPG key passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

can try adding -k arg when you do;

```
ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `~/.ssh/config` does **not** contain

`UseKeychain yes`

which prevents `ssh-add` from persisting to the `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows:
If you went through steps from **@d3r3kk**
and you still have problems, then try this:

WINDOWS:

- delete .bashrc file
- this file is usually located in C:\Users\myusername

Answer (score 0):

### How to properly run the SSH-Agent on Windows

None of the existing answers solved the problem to satisfaction for me. Here's how it should be done according to Microsoft:

Start a powershell console with admin rights:

- press `⊞ Win` to open start menu, type `powershell`, press `ctr` `shift` `enter`

Add the OpenSSH included in Windows to your `PATH` variable:

```
setx PATH "c:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/;$Env:PATH;"
```

Close the powershell terminal and open a new one.

Enter the following commands to ensure the openssh agent runs as a service in the background:

```
# enable automatic start
Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic

# start it now
Start-Service ssh-agent
```

Now the service should be running, you can check via

```
Get-Service ssh-agent
```

Load your private key into the ssh-agent, e.g.

```
ssh-add $env:USERPROFILE/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement#user-key-generation

You should now be able to use your private key without entering the password every time.