# clone github wiki to local repo

Tags: github

I am attempting to clone a github wiki and make a local repository for use with RStudio similar to my use of github with the main repo the wiki is located in.  I am attempting to clone the wiki [per the instructions](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Editing-Wiki-Locally) and here is the error output from the command line:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\trinker\GitHub>git clone  git@github.com:trinker/qdap.wiki.git
Cloning into 'qdap.wiki'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I searched for the error mesage at stackoverflow and get this post [(LINK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560892/permissions-error-github-ssh-key-not-recognized).  The error messages are pretty much identical.  The difference between myself and that poster is I'm not comfortable witht he command line and don't know what to type in to fix the problem.  I attempted this guy's fix [(LINK)](http://imikay.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/github-permission-denied-publickey/), and this is the result:

```
C:\Users\trinker\GitHub>set HOME=C:\Users\trinker

C:\Users\trinker\GitHub>ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/trinker/.ssh/id_rsa): C:\Users\tri
nker\.ssh
C:\Users\trinker\.ssh already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? n

C:\Users\trinker\GitHub>ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/trinker/.ssh/id_rsa):
/c/Users/trinker/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /c/Users/trinker/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /c/Users/trinker/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
d6:ce:b5:23:0c:0d:c0:31:9f:8e:32:34:b9:79:43 trinker@TRINKER-HP

C:\Users\trinker\GitHub>CD C:\Users\trinker\GitHub

C:\Users\trinker\GitHub>git clone  git@github.com:trinker/qdap.wiki.git
Cloning into 'qdap.wiki'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

C:\Users\trinker\GitHub>
```

*NOTE I changed a few characters in the key as I wasn't sure if this was an unsafe thing to be posting.*

Windows 7 users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional to creating a new pair of keys, you also need to tell GitHub about them. At the bottom of [this help page](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) you will find detailed instructions:

> - Go to your Account Settings
> - Click "SSH Keys" in the left sidebar
> - Click "Add SSH key"
> - Paste your key into the "Key" field
> - Click "Add key"
> - Confirm the action by entering your GitHub password

You can also remove your old key in the same settings, since you probably won't need them anymore.