# upgrade openSSH 7.2p in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, upgrade, openssh, pci-compliance

I have a server running Ubuntu 14.04, but I have an issue with PCI requirements. I have installed in my server OpenSSH 6.6p1, then I upgraded it to OpenSSH 7.2p, compiling the code with **make and make install directly from repositories from OpenSSH**, but it seems something is broken because I continue getting the old version after I check `dpkg -l openssh\*`:

```
ii openssh-client 1:6.6p1-2ubunt amd64 secure shell (SSH) client, 
ii openssh-server 1:6.6p1-2ubunt amd64 secure shell (SSH) server,
ii openssh-sftp-serve 1:6.6p1-2ubunt amd64 secure shell (SSH) sftp server
```

And PCI scanner continues reporting the same issue about that I have to install the latest version of OpenSSH.

This is the CVI Id of the issue: CVE-2016-3115

Comment: The reason dpkg still shows the older version is that it doesn't know about the one you compiled from source.

Comment: I upgraded my version Ubuntu to the latest LTS version in order to solve this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I needed to install the newest OpenSSH as well but I wanted to install it via a package instead of compiling from source.

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main universe multiverse'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server=1:7.3p1-1
```

It worked for me. (Technically only main and universe were necessary here)

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.3p1 Ubuntu-1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Edit (2017-10-04): This answer has been receiving some attention lately and might be out of date now. Remember only `main` and `universe` were necessary from this, and I specifically wanted to install this as a package instead of compiling from source. Please be careful with typing random commands from the internet, no matter how well-meaning the stranger (in this case me) is!

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. It worked for me on 14.04.

Comment: Also worked for me, except I needed a more recent version in zesty, same steps, just change yakkety to zesty, and the ssh version to 1:7.4p1-10

Comment: This will also cause apt to want to upgrade *a lot* of other packages, too, no? Perhaps the repository should be disabled once you have your new ssh version. But then, how to get security updates?

Comment: Word of caution: adding this new apt repository caused apt to want to install and remove a whole bunch of packages, which ended up bricking my Ubuntu installation to the point of uselessness (no wifi access, no window manager, couldn't mount external drives, etc).

Comment: Bricked mine too. Lesson learnt; don't blindly do what stack overflow tells you to do.

Comment: just do a  sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main universe multiverse'
after installing ssh and it should be safe.

Comment: this works for me on 14.04: https://gist.github.com/techgaun/df66d37379df37838482c4c3470bc48e

Comment: that solution didnt work for me on 14.04. it added this line "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main universe multiverse" to /etc/apt/sources.list which breaks apt-get update. i removed manually and now i can do 'apt-get update' but still no ssh upgrade was done.

Answer (score 6):

**Tested on Ubuntu 16.04**

upgrades ssh-client to latest version. 
updates alot of other stuff!

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main universe multiverse'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server=1:7.4p1-10
```

remove repository that was added so extra updates don't happen later:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main'
sudo apt-get update
```

*note: 
For 17.04 change yakety to zesty (untested)*

Comment: Worked perfectly, even inside Windows Subsystem for Linux running Ubuntu. This should be the accepted answer. You forgot a single quote after `main` in the remove step.

Comment: getting `Version '1:7.4p1-10' for 'openssh-server' was not found`

Comment: tried again and worked for me. Are you sure you added the old-releases repo and ran `apt-get update`?

Comment: This should *not* be the accepted answer as it completely ignores the original question, which is to install a new openssh on Ubuntu *14.04*. I won't downvote it, but it won't get my upvote either.

Answer (score 3):

There are two answers already mentioning the recompile. The way they suggest it may not sound like to be a safe option if you are already connected with ssh. Also they fail to suggest what to do with OpenSSL 1.0.2 vs 1.1.0 issue as by default ./configure finds on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the 1.1.0 version of OpenSSL. To patch OpenSSL 7.7 sources to work with OpenSSL 1.1.0 here is a patch:

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/openssh.html

```
wget http://mirror.exonetric.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.7p1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssh-7.7p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.7p1
wget http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/patches/blfs/svn/openssh-7.7p1-openssl-1.1.0-1.patch
patch -Np1 -i ./openssh-7.7p1-openssl-1.1.0-1.patch
```

And here comes the trick: you can have TWO SSHDs so you will not lose the current connection. We will install this other sshd to /opt and its config will be in /opt/etc

```
./configure --prefix=/opt
make ## in the end make will write where it will install, double check everything will go to /opt
make install
nano /opt/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Here edit the port, take it away from 22 to for example 1888 (make sure port is forwarded/opened/etc)

And now you can start the new sshd

```
/opt/sbin/sshd
```

Make sure on restart something (for example systemd) will start this other ssh too.

The 2 sshds are now running simultaneously. You can try to connect with this newly built one. When done, you can safely remove the outdated and security update lacking openssh6.6 from apt, or at least stop the daemon and remove the daemon from startup.

And you are one step closer to a secure system.

Comment: Updated address to the patch: https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/patches/downloads/openssh/openssh-7.7p1-openssl-1.1.0-1.patch

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to if you are using Ubuntu LTS. It seems like the Ubuntu Security Team pushes the patches to you! A detailed [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966571):

Tools like Qualys and nmap are not that smart to figure this out. You can visit the ubuntu package changelog [page](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh_6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10/changelog) [For my case the package was openssh-server6.6] to see if the patch has been provided.

At max to be safe, just do sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade openssh-server to get the patches.

Answer (score 0):

This is an edit from @dszakal's comment since I did not have exactly the same things to do (Ubuntu 16 here).

```
cd
wget http://mirror.exonetric.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.7p1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssh-7.7p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.7p1
wget http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/patches/blfs/svn/openssh-7.7p1-openssl-1.1.0-1.patch
patch -Np1 -i ./openssh-7.7p1-openssl-1.1.0-1.patch
./configure --prefix=/opt
make
sudo make install
cp ~/openssh-7.7p1/sshd_config /opt/etc/
cp ~/openssh-7.7p1/ssh_config /opt/etc/

sudo nano /opt/etc/sshd_config

# Uncomment the lines I wrote below
---------------------------------------------
Port 33333 # You can change the port here
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
---------------------------------------------

# Then launch the service
sudo /opt/sbin/sshd
```

Then try to log in with your usual credentials, it should work.

Nmap report :

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE VERSION
33333/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 7.7 (protocol 2.0)
```

Now we will transfer the new SSH to port 22. I logged in on port 33333 to disabled the old SSH service & changed 33333 to 22 in /opt/etc/sshd_config

```
sudo service ssh stop
sudo nano /opt/etc/sshd_config
Port 22

# Then re-launch the service
sudo /opt/sbin/sshd
```

Then try to log in with your usual credentials, it should work.

Nmap report :

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 7.7 (protocol 2.0)
```

Works like a charm big thanks to @dszakal !!

Answer (score -6):

Updated to latest using:

```
wget http://mirror.exonetric.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.5p1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssh-7.5p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.5p1
./configure
make
sudo make install
```