# Giving an SSH key passphrase with a PowerShell script

Tags: git, powershell, ssh

Every morning I come into work and execute a couple of git commands to bring me up to date with my team. They are as follows:

```
git remote update
git merge main/master
```

I use PowerShell as my go-to command line tool, and whenever I enter the first command (`git remote update`) I get a prompt asking me for my SSH key passphrase:

> Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa':

Usually I would just go ahead and enter this, but I am looking to automate the process using a PowerShell script. What I've done is put my passphrase into a .txt file (not the most secure, but I can address on that once the pipeline works) and I pull it out every time I run the script. But I can't see a way to pass it to the command? Here is my code:

```
Set-Location C:\path\to\repo
$pass = Get-Content C:\path\to\passphrase.txt -First 1
git remote update
git merge main/master
```

I expected that once `git remote update` ran it would prompt me for the passphrase as usual before continuing, and planned to build from there, but it didn't. It just fails with a git error:

```
git : Permission denied, please try again.
At line:3 char:1
+ git remote update
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Permission denied, please try again.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I pass my passphrase `$pass` to the `git remote update` command?

Comment: If you end up putting your passphrase into a plain text file, why not just use an SSH key without a passphrase to begin with. Alternatively, you could use ssh-agent to access your key without the need to prompt for the key, or you could use a https URL to your repository which makes Git for Windows store your credentials in the Windows credential store (so you are also not prompted for a password).

Comment: Having a key without passphrase is just as secure as having the passphrase in plaintext right next to the key. Just remove the passphrase from your key.

Comment: The plan is to improve security at a later date - I'll figure something out once I know that the process is doable. Security *is* a concern, but right now I'm looking to get the thing working and will build from there.

Comment: The thing you are looking for is called [ssh-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) and there is a [question how to use it at windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18404272/2303202). Though I would say once a day is pretty reasonable frequency to enter your password.

Comment: You can [add passphrase or remove it](https://serverfault.com/questions/50775/how-do-i-change-my-private-key-passphrase), so you could just remove it for now and set it back later as you set up the proper solution.

Comment: @max630 I know... it's more of a *remembering* to do it kind of a problem. If I just have the one script to run every morning I'm not going to forget a command. Also, I anticipate the number of daily commands I'm going to have to run to increase significantly in the near future, so it would be nice to have something set up which I can just add to.