# Every time reopen git bash: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: github

I have done serval times
[How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)

But, every time I close git bash and reopen it. It prompts
[image]
Then I input

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ssh.txt
input my password
```

can resolve this problem. But when I reopen the git bash, I have to do everything again. How can I avoid this boring operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc` in order to run your `ssh-agent` for you: [see here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404557/6309).

That way, you won't have to repeat those commands every time you open  a new bash.

See also "[Auto-launching `ssh-agent` on Git for Windows](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows)", from GitHub.

Comment: There is no .bashrc  in there. There is .bash_history and .gitconfig.

Comment: @zhang Then you can *create* a file called `.bashrc` in your `%USERPROFILE%` folder, where you put what is described in https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows.