# How do you avoid typing the password of your ssh key each time, on Linux and Windows with OpenSSH?

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I use a password-protected ssh key (RSA). That means that I need to type the password to decipher the key before using it.

I noticed that on some computers, I don't need to type the pass of my ssh key each time I need to use it.

On my Windows computer, as well as some Linux servers, I need to do it.

I use OpenSSH on Windows (not Putty), so it is the same key as Linux. Stored in the /.shh directory.

Having a password-protected key is good in case someone steals it. But typing the password each time is annoying.

Is there a way to have my computers, on Windows and Linux, remember it?

I use it from the shell (default Ubuntu terminal and PowerShell, often from VS Code).

Thanks

I tried this, but no success:

```s
(base) PS C:\code> ssh-add -k C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa  
Enter passphrase for C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa: 
Identity added: C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa (C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa)
(base) PS C:\code> git fetch
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Too late, can only close it.

Comment: I have moved (and edited) this question to Super User. https://superuser.com/questions/1750783/how-do-you-avoid-typing-the-password-of-your-ssh-key-ea ch-time-on-linux-and-win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh-agent is the process that keeps your passphrase after the initial unlocking, so you don't need to type it every time

[Linux Basic Tutorial on ssh-agent](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-ssh-agent-for-authentication-on-linux-unix/)

[Windows SSH documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement)

[Git Bash for Windows documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404557/14260454)

Comment: I have moved this question to https://superuser.com/questions/1750783/how-do-you-avoid-typing-the-password-of-your-ssh-key-each-time-on-linux-and-win.  Please consider moving your answer there. Please also @mention me here so I can upvote your answer there. Then it's probably best to delete this answer.