# Specify which SSH to use

Tags: git, openssh, ssh-agent

I am using windows 10 with OpenSSH, Git installed. Now I have setup to use ssh key for git communication. I used ssh-add to add key in ssh-agent. The problem is git uses its own local ssh-agent and I have added a key in windows open ssh-agent. Running `where ssh-agent` returns two different location.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh-agent.exe
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe
```

I would like to specify in git which ssh-agent to use.

Comment: Can you also share the output of `where git`? Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/19792331/1012381

Comment: Output of `where git` 
`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `GIT_SSH` to the path of the OpenSSH executable (`C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`). After this, Git should use the *ssh-agent* of OpenSSH.