# Cache http git passwords in windows: mysysgit

Tags: git, version-control

Git: How can I cache password locally in windows machine. I have mysysgit and tortoisegit

**Edit:**
I use https

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/370030/285619

Comment: Are you authenticating with ssh or https?

Comment: @Will, This is about http git and not ssh auth. The linked Q is with ssh

Comment: Sorry, its kind of unclear exactly how this applies to programming/software development tools.  Can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: @Will How is this unclear?  I had the same question.  I consider Git Version Control a development tool.  I have used other so-called version control tools that were more of a hindrance.  I call these Developer-Control tools.  :-)

Comment: @MarkGood: It would have to be storage of a password for those git apps is different than for any other app on your machine.

Answer (score 5):

In [a more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417918/can-i-add-a-username-password-to-git-clone-using-the-recursive-option-for-su/5418892#5418892), [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) points out that you can put your username and password for a particular host that you access over `https` in a file called `_netrc` in your home directory, and git will use them for the HTTP transport.  For example, if you're trying to access the repository referred to by the URL `https://you@github.com/you/project.git`, you would put the following in `_netrc`:

```
machine github.com
  login you
  password yourpassword
```

Comment: Seems that should be "login" instead of "username" in the second line

Comment: @ChristophRüegg: oops, thank-you for pointing that out - I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [git-credential-winstore](https://github.com/anurse/git-credential-winstore) to save git passwords in Windows credentials manager

Comment: git-credential-winstore requires .NET 4

Comment: If you've installed git within Cygwin, it does not recognize normal Windows paths. Install GitCredentialWinstore using normal cmd.exe: git-credentials-winstore.exe -i C:\Cygwin\bin\git.exe and then in Cygwin: $ git config --replace-all --global credential.helper /cygdrive/c/Users/..youruserid../AppData/Roaming/GitCredStore/git-credential-winstore.exe

Answer (score 1):

Since msysgit 1.8.0, there is also a built-in credential helper program `git-credential-wincred`, which does not require .NET framework.

However, it is missing from current installation package.