# Difference between SmartGit and TortoiseGit credential?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, smartgit

In Windows box, I use TortoiseGit to clone remote repository with private key and passphrase. Everything seems ok.

In Linux box, I searched and got SmartGit. It seems very useful but I can not credential to remote repository with same private and passphrase.

Someone tell me what's going between them and how to solved that problem in Linux box. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to convert the private key file to OpenSSH format. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788813/smartgit-wont-authenticate-with-ssh/8796329#8796329).

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the system SSH client for SmartGit:

[image: ssh options]

Then you should be able to copy your public/private keys to your `$HOME/.ssh` directory (provided said directory is [correctly protected](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html): `chmod 700`, and same for your private key: `chmod 600`)

Comment: Note to self: for passphrase management for TortoiseGit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370030/why-git-cant-remember-my-passphrase-under-windows

Comment: Thanks VonC for answer my question. I use Smartgit as SSH client by default and I copy private key to .ssh directory and chmod but i still cannot credential to remote repository , I do the same on windows with smartgit and cannot credential . :(

Comment: @user1129413: but, since I don't know exactly how the "SmartGit as SSH client" works, my point was for you to use the *other* option (I know the screenshot doesn't reflect that, but I took it from the SmartGit feature page). Ie "Use system SSH client". And then see if your files (public/private keys) are recognized from `$HOME/.ssh`.