# SmartGit won't authenticate with ssh

Tags: git, ssh, smartgit

I have a webserver with gitolite installed and where i login using my ssh key. Normally i just use git on the server itself using the command line but for a new project i need to clone a repo on my windows pc and i would like to use SmartGit for this.

But i've spend several hours already just to clone the repo via Smartgit. As remote Git i use the url i normally would use on the server: me@my-server:the-repo then after a while i get a dialogue box 'SSH Authentication' and i select my private key, as i would do for pagent, and put in my Passphrase. But when i click login it just tries to connect for a while and then shows me the 'SSH Authentication' dialogue box again. No error message or anything.

I tried the clone the repo with the same data via command line and that works just fine. So is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Needed to save my ssh private key as an OpenSSH key in [PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) because SmartGit only understand that format.

Comment: That's weird, but if you click the PuTTYgen *"Save private key"* or *"Save public key"* it will not work. You need save via menu *Conversions → Export OpenSSH Key*. This file will accpeted

Comment: on Windows, you can also switch to internal SSH tool in SmartGit preferences - it asks for ssh key passwords and just works

Answer (score 13):

Yes, that's it!

I just want to go in details to help the ones starting from scratch:

on windows you can do the following procedure:

1. Install msysgit from [Here](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list)
2. To generate public/private key pair as needed by many git servers (like Assembla) use **PuTTYgen** 
   that you find [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html): 
   click on **Generate** and **move your mouse** until it tells you that the key is generated. Optionally, enter a passphrase to protect your private key
3. Save or copy the public key at your need
4. Save private key to use with SmartGit using menu voice **Conversions/Export OpenSSH key**
5. Use the last file to authenticate in SmartGit

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use putty as ssh client, please follow the below steps:

1. Edit|Preferences|Commands|Authentication, choose `Use System SSH
   Client`
2. In windows system variables, set GIT_SSH=plink (where
   putty's plink.exe location)

After that, please use **pageant** and load the private key

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [SmartGit](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) on MacOS X, this problem causes an unexpected dialog to be displayed in the Finder:

`"SSH - Enter passphrase for key '/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa':"`

And it pops up when SmartGit is launched. It looks like this:

[image: SmartGit SSH passphrase prompt]

It's odd and confusing how looks like a Finder dialog, with no reference at all to SmartGit. It's usually caused by the SSH key password not being stored in the [Keychain Access app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(software)). That's where SmartGit will look for it. You'll need to add it in there, like this:

- For MacOS 12 Monterey, use this in the Terminal:

`ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa    (assuming id_rsa is your private key file)`

- For MacOS 11 (Big Sur), 10.15 (Catalina), 10.14 (Mojave), 10.13 (High Sierra) and below, use this in the Terminal:

`ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa    (assuming id_rsa is your private key file)`

**The above commands are usually needed after restarting your computer.** See also these guides:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically
- https://superuser.com/questions/88470/how-to-use-mac-os-x-keychain-with-ssh-keys
- [SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase)

Comment: I got this problem after every restart, does anybody know why it's happening and how to prevent it once and for all?

Comment: Nevermind, I found an answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264974

Answer (score 4):

I found it easier to change SmartGit | Preference | Commands | Executables to use "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe", and then set GIT_SSH=plink in the system env.

Answer (score 0):

1. generate a PEM private key

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM

(add the public key to your git host)

2. clone (or re-clone) your project form smargit UI,

(In my case, I had to remove my local project and then clone it from smargit, i wasn't able to make it work with an existing local project, smartgit always told me the private key (id_rsa) was wrong or the passphrase was wrong, It took me one day to succeed, i hate so much smartgit!!!)