# npm install private github repositories by dependency in package.json

Tags: node.js, github, dependencies, npm, package.json

I'm trying to install github private repository by npm that includes other private github repositories as dependency.

Have tried a lot of ways and posts but none is working. Here is what i'm doing :

```
npm install git+https://github.com/myusername/mygitrepository.git
```

in package.json  is like :

```
"dependencies": {
    "repository1name": "git+https://github.com/myusername/repository1.git",
    "repository2name": "git+https://github.com/myusername/repository2.git"
}
```

What is the the right way to do it?

Comment: git+https://<token-from-github>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<GitRepo>.git
It supports authentication and works fine in all cases.

Comment: you need to specify the branch, commit or tag for it to work EJ: #master->git+https://github.com/myusername/repository2.git#master

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The following worked just fine in all scenarios i needed :

```
"dependencies": {
"GitRepo": "git+https://<token-from-github>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<GitRepo>.git"
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference link for this solution?

Comment: @Ian : I read it somewhere but don't have reference link. I'm using it in production for over a year without any problem.
You can get oauth token from Github as : Settings -> Applications -> Personal Access Token -> Generate new token.
This token can have read/write or both privileges as per your use case.

Comment: @lan : for bitbucket you can use following syntax :
git clone https://<bitbucket-team-token>:x-oauth-basic@bitbucket.org/<team>/<BitRepo>

<bitbucket-team-token> can be obtained from :  Team -> Manage Team -> API Key

Comment: @vashishatashu, thanks for a great idea. However, I get "fatal: blahblah not found" when trying this, even though I have granted access to the user in question to the repo. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a specific npm command I need to execute for this to work? I'm using `npm install` but I'm just getting the plain files instead of an actual git clone..

Comment: Does this work for private repos that I have access to?

Comment: @Danielo515 : Yes this is exactly what the above given syntax works. 
If you face any problem just let me know.

Comment: @vashishatashu, it was working on node 4, but for my current version of node it does not work. If I include the git information into the `package.json` and I run `npm -i` I don't get any error, but it does not install the package. You know why? This are my versions: node --version
v6.2.1
npm --version
3.9.3

Comment: Here's a nice article on this technique: https://web.archive.org/web/20170506085956/http://rzrsharp.net/2013/07/02/private-github-repos-with-npm-and-heroku.html

Comment: @Danielo515 : I am still on node v4 and right now do not have a active Github plan so can not say what's wrong.

Comment: I used this reference: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/

Comment: There is more detail on this other StackOverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/a/28729646/965352

Comment: How should be for gitlab private servers?

Comment: Hi , i want to deploy my repo as a public repo so i don't want to disclose the token, what can be done ?

Comment: Hi, Can you specify a folder I need in the repository?

Comment: Since your own access token from Github is visible directly in your package.json, it does not seem to be a safe solution.

Comment: If you push your code to a repository, your token will be visible to anyone with access to the repository.

Comment: This solution isn't secure, you should use the solution below that creates ~/.gitconfig file, rather than storing your gh token in your package.json. The gh token is supposed to be treated like a password so ...

Answer (score 197):

Try this:

```
"dependencies" : {
  "name1" : "git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish",
  "name2" : "git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish"
}
```

You could also try this, where visionmedia/express is name/repo:

```
"dependencies" : {
   "express" : "visionmedia/express"
}
```

Or (if the npm package module exists):

```
"dependencies" : {
  "name": "*"
}
```

Taken from [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

Comment: npm ERR! Failed resolving git HEAD (https://github.com/user/reponame.git) fatal: ambiguous argument 'commit-ish':  unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: Doesn't work. the #xxxx isn't required as if not given its considered to be master and all my work is in master. 

Any other idea?

Comment: Same outcome if you remove the header (#commit-ish)?

Comment: What's the name of your repository?

Comment: I can't reveal its for some client.

actually if i remove dependencies, it works just fine. 
1 module gets installed. The issue starts when i give git dependencies.

Comment: Does the git repositories have a package.json file?

Comment: If the dependencies exist in the npm package module you could also try "name1" : "*"

Comment: Did get the desired result by using git+ssh method.

Still couldn't get   it through git-http.

Comment: @vashishatashu, regarding `fatal: ambiguous argument 'commit-ish': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` Pretty obvious that `commit-ish` is just a sample word which you should replace with a `sha` of a specific commit that you need. (or remove that `#commit-ish` at all if you need the latest commit in your master branch)

Comment: `As of version 1.1.65, you can refer to GitHub urls as just “foo”: “user/foo-project”.` [npmjs docs reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls)

Answer (score 113):

For those of you who came here for public directories, from the npm docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

#### Git URLs as Dependencies

Git urls can be of the form:

```
git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
```

The commit-ish can be any tag, sha, or branch which can be supplied as an argument to git checkout. The default is master.

Comment: What does "for public directories" mean?

Comment: `As of version 1.1.65, you can refer to GitHub urls as just “foo”: “user/foo-project”.` [npmjs docs reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls)

Comment: What does the protocol `git+https://` mean? Use `git` protocol for cloning and pull new changes while pushing through `https`?

Comment: npm install
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/liihuu/KLineChart.git
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,20.205.243.166' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

Answer (score 94):

The accepted answer works, but I don't like much the idea to paste secure tokens into the `package.json`

I have found it elsewhere, just run this one-time command [as documented in the git-config manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf).

```
git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
```

`GITHUB_TOKEN` may be setup as environmnet variable or pasted directly

and then I install private github repos like: `npm install user/repo --save`

---

works also in Heroku, just setup the above `git config ...` command as `heroku-prebuild` script in `package.json` and setup `GITHUB_TOKEN` as Heroku config variable.

Comment: This also works in Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services Build Chain, where I execute it as a "command" just before the `npm install` step.

Comment: Spectacular!  Great solution for CI environments!
I did have to modify it a bit; I had to change the end to `...insteadOf ssh://git@github.com`

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect my npm. It's still using ssh when running `npm install user/repo --save`. Is there something I need to configure?

Comment: Excellent solution for CI environment where setting up SSH is a pain(CloudBuild)! Thank you very much for this one!

Comment: Amazing. For me, similar as @ScottRippey, I had to change the end to `.insteadOf "https://github.com"`

Answer (score 74):

There are multiple ways to do it as people point out, but the shortest versions are:

```
// from master
"depName": "user/repo",

// specific branch
"depName": "user/repo#branch",

// specific commit
"depName": "user/repo#commit",

// private repo
"depName": "git+https://[TOKEN]:x-oauth-basic@github.com/user/repo.git"
```

e.g.

```
"dependencies" : {
  "hexo-renderer-marked": "amejiarosario/dsa.jsd#book",
  "hexo-renderer-marked": "amejiarosario/dsa.js#8ea61ce",
  "hexo-renderer-marked": "amejiarosario/dsa.js",
}
```

Comment: Succinct answer for public repositories, which unfortunately was not the OP's question.  Still, it helped me and I appreciated it.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the private repo case

Comment: how would you write as to take a folder from a repo as a dependency ? 
for instance from my repo i want to take /src/util  as a package

Comment: If you are using a tag created by `npm version patch` or something like that make sure you include the 'v' 

"some-repo" : "myusername/some-repo#v1.1..2"

Answer (score 31):

```
"dependencies": {
  "some-package": "github:github_username/some-package"
}
```

or just

```
"dependencies": {
  "some-package": "github_username/some-package"
}
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls

Answer (score 14):

Since Git uses `curl` under the hood, you can use **`~/.netrc`** file with the credentials. For GitHub it would look something like this:

```
machine github.com
  login <github username>
  password <password OR github access token>
```

If you choose to use `access tokens`, it can be generated from:

> Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens

This should also work if you are using Github Enterprise in your own corporation. just put your enterprise github url in the `machine` field.

Comment: worked for me with `machine github.com login <token>` on one line and `"package": "https://github.com/acme/privaterepo.git#commit-ish"` or directly with `npm install https://github.com/acme/privaterepo.git#commit-ish`

Comment: This worked! Possibly the only solution for https without using token to url. But can you tell that is it safe to store password unencrypted like this ?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a more detailed version of how to use the Github token without publishing in the `package.json` file.

1. Create personal github access token
2. Setup url rewrite in ~/.gitconfig

```
git config --global url."https://<TOKEN HERE>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf https://x-oauth-basic@github.com/
```

3. Install private repository. Verbose log level for debugging access errors.

```
npm install --loglevel verbose --save git+https://x-oauth-basic@github.com/<USERNAME HERE>/<REPOSITORY HERE>.git#v0.1.27
```

In case access to Github fails, try running the `git ls-remote ...` command that the `npm install will print`

Answer (score 2):

Further, in order to make key's access secure

1. Create .env file at the same directory level where package.json resides.
2. Mention PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN=******************************* into .env file
3. Dont forget to add '.env' into .gitingore list which will prevent exposing key to outside world while you make git commit to your repo.
4. Now you can add your dependency in package.json as below,

> Package.json

> "dependencies": {
> ...
> "my-private-github-repo": "git+https://${ENV.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/USER/abcd-repo-3.4.0.git",
> ...
> }

There are other ways using 'DOTENV' npm package, but it could not do much when we are trying to resolve "Github" package dependency. Above seems to be straight forward solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase#25721662)

Using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` without a local keychain.

This avoids having to mess with tokens.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the dependency that is not anchored to master nor to a particular commit, you can do it by using semver. Like that:

```
"dependencies": {
  "some-package": "github:github_username/some-package#semver:^1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the github repos that you try to add as a dependency to your package.json file needs to have its own package.json file defined.

Answer (score 0):

For my private repository reference I didn't want to include a secure token, and none of the other simple (i.e. specifying only in package.json) worked.  Here's what did work:

1. Went to GitHub.com
2. Navigated to Private Repository
3. Clicked "Clone or Download" and Copied URL (which didn't match the examples above)
4. Added #commit-sha
5. Ran npm install