# How to use private Github repo as npm dependency

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, package.json

How do I list a private Github repo as a `"dependency"` in `package.json`? I tried [npm's Github URLs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls) syntaxes like `ryanve/example`, but doing `npm install` in the package folder gives "could not install" errors for the private dependencies. Is there a special syntax (or some other mechanism) for depending on private repos?

Answer (score 415):

It can be done via [https and oauth](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#https-cloning-with-oauth-tokens) **or** ssh.

**https and oauth:** [create an access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/) that has "repo" scope and [then use this syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308172806/http://rzrsharp.net/2013/07/02/private-github-repos-with-npm-and-heroku.html):

```
"package-name": "git+https://<github_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"
```

or

**ssh:** [setup ssh](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) and then use this syntax:

```
"package-name": "git+ssh://git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git"
```

(note the use of colon instead of slash before user)

Comment: Or if you have ssh set up at github, skip the token and use:  `"<package>": "git+ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git`

Comment: "package-name": "git+ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"

can also be

"package-name": "git+ssh://git@github.com:<org>/<repo>.git"

Comment: How do you have it always on to the latest release?

Comment: Add #master to the end

Comment: How do you make it always fetch the latest commit?

Comment: I setup my ssh keys (they were already setup but still received 'authentication failed') - so tried deleting and re-adding and making sure they were added to my ssh agent + restarting my computer and none of it seems to be working :( any other thoughts?

Comment: had to change `git+ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git` to `git+ssh://git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git` note the colon after `github.com` instead of `/`

Comment: Using this approach, is possible to work with package versioning?

Comment: @Richard Yes, if you use git tags to tag your releases and append the the tag to your URI like `#v0.1.0` https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Comment: @Richard It could be any git tag that you've created. I do suggest using semver.

Comment: Umm, are you going to commit the access token to Git? Does not sound wise from security viewpoint..

Comment: @Kitanotori the `ssh` method is probably more secure in that respect.

Comment: `"package-name": "git+https://<github_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"` did not work for me. Surprisingly switching token and x-oauth-basic did the job. So, `"package-name": "git+https://x-oauth-basic:<github_token>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"` works for me.
please note that I am on gitlab and not github.

Comment: I need to use a token in the package so I can avoid the prompt, but how do you keep your key private so that you don't commit it to your repository? I'm trying to use an environment variable without luck.

Comment: Over `https` putting `x-oauth-basic` as the username is not necessary: `"package-name": "git+https://<github_token>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"` works as well.

Comment: it works well, thanks @ryanve, one more question - is there any way to add versioning? after upgrading the repo and npm install does not bring updated code.

Comment: @blackiii Yes with like `#v7.7.7` in URL like examples on https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Comment: Thank you @ryanve, I was able to do that with git tagging system, all works fine, :+1

Comment: The ssh answer provided by @ryanve works great, however, having a collaborator yarn install the repo where the private repo is a dependency indicates a Permission denied (publickey) error. The collaborator has access to the repo and can clone it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's the bit I don't understand... if the personal access token is "personal" how can you commit it to the package.json when it is shared by multiple developers? Or is it global?

Comment: I don't know if this is such a great idea. The "repo" scope has full read/write access on the repository. Do you really want to be commiting that to source control? Would be okay if there was a read only option but there isn't from what I can tell.

Comment: Is this idea going to work for azure repo as well?

Comment: @DaveStewart You'd have to make a (private or otherwise) Github app, which can be installed to your organization's repo(s), and which can have its own access token with the necessary permissions. It's kind of a pain, but that's the "right" solution to avoid using your own PAT.

Answer (score 38):

### NPM *without* access token in  repo

This method requires anyone who uses the package to authenticate with their own personal access token rather than a single group token, which allows the repo to be free of access tokens. You also don't need to create a new access token every time a user should no longer be granted access, instead, removing a user from the repo in GitHub will automatically remove their package access.

**This is a condensed version of GitHub's NPM guide:** https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry

---

#### Publish Your GitHub Repo as an NPM Package

1. Create a personal access token in developer settings: https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. Login to NPM

```
npm login --scope=@<USERNAME of repo owner in lowercase> --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com

Username: <Your personal GitHub username>
Password: <Create a GitHub Access Token with your account and paste it here>
Email: <Email associated with the same account>
```

**For example:** where user @Bobby wants to publish github.com/Jessica/my-npm-package as an NPM package

```
npm login --scope=@jessica --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com

Username: bobby
Password: yiueytiupoasdkjalgheoutpweoiru
Email: bobby@example.com
```

3. Update the `package.json`, following the format below.

```
  "name": "@jessica/my-npm-package",
  "repository": "git://github.com/jessica/my-npm-package.git",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry":"https://npm.pkg.github.com"
  },
```

4. To publish the NPM package, run:

```
npm publish
```

---

#### Install a Private NPM Package in a Project

1. Login to NPM in the same exact way as step 2 above.
2. Install the package with `npm install @jessica/my-npm-package`

**Done!**

Keep reading if your project will have GitHub Actions scripts that need to install this private NPM package.

---

#### GitHub Actions: How to Install a Private NPM Package

In a CI environment, you'll also need `npm login` to similarly authenticate. Otherwise, `npm install` will fail, since it doesn't have access to the private NPM package. One way to pre-configure this is to use a `.npmrc` file; however, this commits auth credentials to the repo with that file. So, another way is to use the NPM tool [npm-cli-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cli-login). There is a requirement that you either use your own personal access token (not optimal: you leave the repo, CI breaks), or set up a GitHub account specifically for CI and create an access token with that account.

1. Create an access token with a CI-only GitHub account or grab an access token from your own GitHub account.
2. Add that access token to your repo as a "secret", in the repo settings.
3. Update your GitHub Actions workflow script to run this step AFTER you install NPM and BEFORE you run `npm install`:

```
- name: Login to GitHub private NPM registry
  env:
    CI_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NAME_OF_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET }}
  shell: bash
  run: |
    npm install -g npm-cli-login
    npm-cli-login -u "USERNAME" -p "${CI_ACCESS_TOKEN}" -e "EMAIL" -r "https://npm.pkg.github.com" -s "@SCOPE"
```

Replace `NAME_OF_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET`, `USERNAME`, `EMAIL` and `SCOPE`.

**For example**

```
- name: Login to GitHub private NPM registry
  env:
    CI_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}
  shell: bash
  run: |
    npm install -g npm-cli-login
    npm-cli-login -u "ci-github-account" -p "${CI_ACCESS_TOKEN}" -e "ci-github-account@example.com" -r "https://npm.pkg.github.com" -s "@jessica"
```

**Done!**

Now when GitHub Actions later run `npm install`, the script will have access to the private NPM package.

**FYI:** If you're familiar with GitHub Actions, you may ask why can't we use `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` which GitHub automatically supplies? The reason is `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` **only** has access to the repo that is running the GitHub Actions, it does not have access to the repo of the private NPM package.

Comment: This is a guide to install a dependency from GitHub **Package Registry**, *not* from a GitHub **repository**

Answer (score 29):

If someone is looking for another option for Git Lab and the options above do not work, then we have another option.  For a local installation of Git Lab server, we have found that the approach, below, allows us to include the package dependency. We generated and use an access token to do so.

```
$ npm install --save-dev https://git.yourdomain.com/userOrGroup/gitLabProjectName/repository/archive.tar.gz?private_token=InsertYourAccessTokenHere
```

Of course, if one is using an access key this way, it should have a limited set of permissions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 19):

With git there is a https format

```
https://github.com/equivalent/we_demand_serverless_ruby.git
```

This format accepts User + password

```
https://bot-user:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@github.com/equivalent/we_demand_serverless_ruby.git
```

So what you can do is create a new user that will be used **just as a bot**, 
add only enough permissions that he can just read the repository you
want to load in NPM modules and just have that directly in your
`packages.json`

```
 Github > Click on Profile > Settings > Developer settings > Personal access tokens > Generate new token
```

In Select Scopes part, check the  on **repo**:  Full control of private  repositories

This is so that token can access private repos that user can see

Now create new group in your organization, add this user to the group and  add only repositories that you expect
to be pulled this way (READ ONLY permission !)

You need to be sure to push this config **only to private repo**

Then you can add this to your   /  packages.json (bot-user is
name of user, xxxxxxxxx is the generated personal token)

```
// packages.json


{
  // ....
    "name_of_my_lib": "https://bot-user:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@github.com/ghuser/name_of_my_lib.git"
  // ...
}
```

https://blog.eq8.eu/til/pull-git-private-repo-from-github-from-npm-modules-or-bundler.html

Comment: So, is it safe to commit this personal access token, and use it in something like Travis CI?

Comment: @ConAntonakos if the project is a Github private repository and you have paid Travis CI that is running  your private Github project repository then yes (kindof, as you are not sharing your credentials publicly)  Also thing to rememmber is that you need to create and use credentials of new  Github user that has only read access to this private repo.  So don't use your personal account :) ...create a bot user account that is easier to lock in case of exposure ;)    ... If  you are building a bank project this will not pass ISO accreditation so then no it's never secure not even store code on GH

Answer (score 7):

I wasn't able to make the accepted answer work in a **Docker** container.

What worked for me was to set the *Personal Access Token* from GitHub in a file called `.netrc`

```
ARG GITHUB_READ_TOKEN
RUN echo -e "machine github.com\n  login $GITHUB_READ_TOKEN" > ~/.netrc 
RUN npm install --only=production --force \
  && npm cache clean --force
RUN rm ~/.netrc
```

in `package.json`

```
"my-lib": "github:username/repo",
```

Answer (score 6):

As of April 2023, the only thing that worked for me using github repo was:

```
npm install https://oauth2:<your-fine-grained-token>@github.com/owner/repo.git
```

or if you want to specify the branch:

```
npm install https://oauth2:<your-fine-grained-token>@github.com/owner/repo.git#master
```

**for example:**

```
npm install https://oauth2:github_pat_51BR4Zf222bFXEXgW0dg3O_Kdfh5dghIFHJUPOTJYdB4ahsqe607ewCaynCLRu3aAINOKhrUk42HsUd@github.com/facebook#master
```

You can create your token here: https://github.com/settings/tokens?type=beta
Read-only permissions are enough for installing and using the repo.

Comment: This worked for me. For anyone wondering, the scope of my fine grained access token was "Contents" Read Only and "Metadata" Read Only, and this was to a single package.

Comment: I thought you meant oauth2 literally. I eventually __replaced it with my username__ and it worked right away, even though the repo was under a github organisation.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is an old question, adding an answer here which works across platforms.

The general [npm v7 syntax](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies) to access private repositories in node_modules is -

```
git+https://<token_name>:<token>@<path_to_repository>.git#<commit>
```

You will have to create an access token with your git service provider with atleast read access.

Following are links for most popular platforms :

- [github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)
- [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)
- [bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html)

Do note github creates token linked to your username and there is no token name, thus, use your username instead of token_name for github.

Comment: I can’t get this to work for a private module on Github using above syntax. The npm install fails saying the repo doesn’t exist. However when I copy and paste the url directly from the error message, it loads successfully in the browser, so it definitely exists! Also tried without token name, just the token, doesn’t work either.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to generate the personal access token and then use them as your password when you login npm.

```
npm login --scope=@dave --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
username: ${github_username}
password: ${personal_access_token}
Email: ${public_email}
```