# how to use gitlab repo in NPM with package.json

Tags: npm, gitlab, package.json

I'm working on a internal project and want to share a tools inside the group.

but if I use the npm tools. it either request the module has registered on npm website or public git repo.

I'm using gitlab. and there is a private token.

`git+https://gitlab-ci-token:\<private token>@<domain>/<username>/<repo_name>.git`

i tried to put it like this in package.json
but it's not working.

Is there a way to install a private gitlab repo with authorization?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Heavily related (check the second answer): http://stackoverflow.com/q/28728665/1233251

Comment: @E_net4 yes. I see that post too. but that one is using github. i tried both. but seems gitlab is not using the same way as github.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43774869/2179157

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your CI pipeline which runs npm to be able to pull a private project from your gitlab as a dependency.

In that case, you can use the deploy keys mechanism in gitlab for that (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys)).

First generate a SSH key pair. You can use `ssh-keygen -t rsa` for that.

Then go to the private repository's gitlab page and locate the `Deploy tokens` setting in: Settings > Repository. There you should paste the public key you just generated.

Then go to the project that runs npm in its CI and locate the `Variables` page. Create a new private variable with the name `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` for instance and paste the private key you generated there.

Finally, in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file add the following so that your private key will be available to your CI environment:

```
- 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
# Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
- eval $(ssh-agent -s)
# Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
- ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

Your CI environment should now be setup so that in can pull your private repository.

Comment: thank you for you reply.
but  what i really want to ask is .
I have a project with a package.json file.

how could i set up a dependancy with correct schema or url with private gitlab repo

Comment: If you do what's decribed in my answer, then you can add your private repository in your package.json with `"git+ssh://git@<gitlaburl>/<username>/<repo_name>.git"`

Comment: @Jawad what username should be used in a Gitlab CI pipeline?

Comment: @7hibault The ssh user to connect to a gitlab repo is always git so a SSH URL will always look like `git@<gitlab_domain>/<username>/<project>.git`

Comment: In both of my comments above, it should read `git@<gitlab_domain>:<username>/<project>.git` (notice the `:` instead of the `/`between the domain and username)

Comment: @Jawad I am using MAC
1) can you detail about the variable page:
"Then go to the project that runs npm in its CI and locate the Variables page. Create a new private variable with the name SSH_PRIVATE_KEY for instance and paste the private key you generated there."
2) when you said private key you mean something like a4:r3:......, the one that is shown key that is shown when you submit the public key?
3) By the way I did not find .gitlab-ci.yml in my project, so created one in the main folder where gitigonre resides.. Did i do correct?

Comment: @Jawad I am trying to setup dev environment so that other developers in project can use the same package.json and just do npm install all the packages.

Comment: @Jawad I am giving my email id as user name.. Is that correct? Sorry for posting multiple times. I got the doubts subsequently and I am not allowed to edit after 5 minutes

Comment: After re-reading the answer, I just realised that my edit suggestion actually wasn't relevant. In fact, there is indeed a section called "Deploy keys" in "Settings > Repository", and my edit only made the answer confusing. If someone could revert my edit so that I don't get +2 reputation for fixing my own mistake, that would be great.