# How to link a deployment script/repo from an application repo in Gitlab CD?

Tags: git, deployment, ansible, gitlab

Let's say you have:

- `Repo A` with a generic application.
- `Repo B` with an Ansible deployment script.

Inside the RepoA CI/CD runner, I want to run the Ansible script from Repo B. What's the best/easiest way to do this?

What I am trying is to create an extra ssh key for RepoB only and feed it into the runner via [Secret Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#secret-variables). Unfortunately, I would have to create a dummy user, that only has access to RepoB for that.

Is there any other ways I could do that? It seems like that should be a pretty common workflow for deployments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, that's a pretty common use case. Gitlab uses what it calls `Deploy Keys` to achieve this (more info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys)).

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248815/how-to-use-gitlab-repo-in-npm-with-package-json/43249425#43249425).

Below is a version of that answer tuned to your specific needs.

First generate a SSH key pair. You can use `ssh-keygen -t rsa` for that.

Then go to Repo B's gitlab page and locate the `Deploy Keys` setting. There you should paste the public key you just generated.

Then go to Repo A locate the `Variables` page. Create a new private variable with the name `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` for instance and paste the private key you generated there.

Finally, in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file add the following so that your private key will be available to your CI environment:

```
- 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
# Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
- eval $(ssh-agent -s)
# Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
- ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

Your Repo A CI environment should now be setup so that in can pull Repo B.

Comment: I guess, I was not aware of `deploy keys` :).

Comment: It's a pretty useful feature when handling several (inter)dependent projects ;)