# How to host a project and its GitLab page under the same namespace?

Tags: gitlab

I have a group named `groupname` and within that group a project named `projectname`. The group has a GitLab page which is available at `http(s)://groupname.gitlab.io/`.

Now I want to create a GitLab page for this project which should be available at `http(s)://groupname.gitlab.io/projectname`. In order to make this happen - as far as I understood from [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/introduction.html?&_ga=1.95220571.63798462.1491939718#project-pages) - the gitlab-page-project needs to be hosted under the group and it's name needs to be `projectname`. But that's already the name of the actual project the page refers to!

While I could host the project under a different path - say `groupname/projectname-doc` - and still rename it to `projectname` it will make both projects show up with the same name in the group's project overview. Am I missing something here or is this the recommended way to host both a project and its GitLab page under the same namespace?

Comment: From what I understand in the docs, you should have a `pages` job in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file of your already existing project. That means you have to have the same version control for the project and its website. It doesn't seem very practical to me...

Comment: This is not possible for me as the master branch of my project reflects the most recent release and I can't release a new version each time I modify the project's documentation. I can't believe this was the intention of the GitLab developers. Or do they mean to only push the `yaml` file in the original project and have the website's source code in a different repo which is somehow linked to the job specified in the `yaml`? I can't figure how this would be realized then.

Comment: The way I would do it would be through `Deploy Keys` and maybe a webhook. Basically add a deploy key to your website project then add a private variable to your actual project and add a `pages` job in your yaml file that will pull the website project and deploy it. Then you could setup a webhook in order to run your main project's CI pipeline everytime you push to your website project. I can write a full fledged answer tomorrow morning if you're interested (not really practical now as I'm on my phone...) here's a pointer in the meantime http://stackoverflow.com/a/43311371/6654146

Comment: @Jawad That would be great as I'm not familiar with deploy keys and how to setup that webhook. All in all that means the pages job will pull the website project onto the build server and use its content for the build process? Where exactly does the build process take place? Within the actual project's repo then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a follow up to the discussion we had in the comments to your question.

## Setting up the deploy keys and the pipeline

First generate a SSH key pair. You can use `ssh-keygen -t rsa` for that.

Then create a gitlab project for the page, let's call it `projectname-docs`. In this project, locate the `Deploy Keys` setting. There you should paste the public key you just generated.

Then go to `projectname` and locate the `Variables` page. Create a new private variable with the name `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` for instance and paste the private key you generated there.

In your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the `projectname` project, add the following so that your private key will be available to your CI environment:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    # Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    # Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - git clone git@gitlab.com:groupname/projectname-docs.git
    - cd projectname-docs
    - mkdir ~/.public
    - cp -r * ~/.public
    - cd ../
    - mv ~/.public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

At this point, every time you push something to your main project, it will pull the `projectname-docs` project and deploy it using Gitlab pages. The docs should then be available.

## Setting up the webhook

What you may want, is to be able to run the main project's pipeline every time you push to `projectname-docs` so the web page is updated.

One way to do this is through [webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#webhooks).

First go to your main project's gitlab page and go to `Settings -> CI/CD Pipelines -> Triggers` and click the `Add Trigger` button. This will create a new token we'll use later.

Then, go to `projectname-docs` and navigate to `Settings -> Integrations` and insert the following for the URL:

```
http://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/ID/ref/REF_NAME/trigger/pipeline?token=TOKEN
```

Where `ID` is the id of `projectname`, `REF_NAME` is the name of the branch or tag to run the pipeline for (e.g `master`) and `TOKEN` is the token you generated in the previous step.

Make sure the `push` event is selected and add the webhook.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So if I understood it correctly the website is served from `~/public` and this is where all my HTML should go? Because I'm building from Sphinx and thus I need to know where to copy the build.

Comment: The HTML needs to be in the root of the `projectname-docs` git repo. Then the Ci will copy everything to the `public` directory. You can put your HTML somewhere else but then change `cp -r * ~/.public` to copy from the correct location. So at the end of the CI pipeline, yes, the HTML needs to be in `~/public`

Comment: All right because I plan to have my documentation source in `projectname-docs` and to add an additional build step to the job (+ followed by copying the resulting files to `~/public`). Thanks!

Comment: I tried to follow your approach and ran the pipeline however I get a
`Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`
I added both public and private key as you mentioned. Also I don't quite understand why the project is cloned from `git@gitlab.io:groupname/projectname-docs.git`. I tried changing it to `git@gitlab.com:groupname/projectname-docs.git` however I get the same error message. Adding the private key the response was `Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (rsa w/o comment)`. @Jawad

Comment: Nevermind, turned out that the public key has been deleted. Actually I wanted to re-add it however deleting it failed with an error message, so I supposed it was still there. Apparently it had been deleted though and this just showed up in the GUI later.

Comment: Just changed gitlab.io to gitlab.com in the answer for future reference.

Comment: To get the page served apparently the HTML content must be placed in a `public` folder which resides in the project's directory (not in the home directory). See [this article](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_four.html#the-public-directory). If the content is placed in a different folder the page won't be served even if you specify that other location under `artifacts`. Also all paths specified under `artifacts` seem to be relative to the `.gitlab.ci.yml` file which resides in the projects directory too.