# NPM install resulting in 401 Unauthorized for private repo

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab

I have the following line in my dependencies in `package.json`:

```
"log": "https://git.mydomain.com/myproject/myrepo/repository/archive.tar.gz?ref=0.1.0",
```

I get the following:

```
km@Karls-MBP ~/dev/vertica (km/ref) $ npm install
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 404 401 Unauthorized: log@https://git.mydomain.com/myproject/myrepo/repository/archive.tar.gz?ref=0.5.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/km/.npm/_logs/2018-02-16T08_49_38_669Y-debug.log
```

I don't know if the issue is GitLab (where the repo exists) or NPM.

- Node v8.9.4
- NPM v5.6.0

Comment: Is the tarball publicly available? If not, you'll need to provide an auth strategy in the package URL. Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28729646/382982) question/answer? Also, it seems unlikely that it'd be an NPM issue, but just in case: try `npm logout && npm login`, ensure there isn't either a stale `$NPM_TOKEN` env var or `_authToken` set in an .npmrc (look in your home directory and the project directory).

Comment: I had to follow these steps to fix the error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

Answer (score 83):

Remove .npmrc from the Home Directory, it should be able to work. I did the same and it works for me.

Comment: That worked for me. In my case, it was "npm install -g @vue/cli" that was printing 401. What's the purpose of this solution?

Comment: What if you need the .npmrc file for authentication to a service on a vpn?

Comment: This will never work with a private repo

Answer (score 19):

My user directory .npmrc file had a stale authtoken as below.

//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=3615fa68-123a-4d72-b99a-772b5b1edc48

By removing this line, the npm installation works fine and no longer throws an authentication error.

Answer (score 17):

You need to add user to npm registery

```
>> npm whoami [ it will return not authorized ]
```

To add new user follow below steps :-

```
>> npm adduser  (then enter your name and complex password and your email)

>> npm whoami   (return your registered name)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error but the reason in my case was different than the above answers:

I discovered that the `package-lock.json` had some of the packages resolved to a private url instead of the typical public npm urls, so deleting the npm lock file and running npm install again solved it

But if this is the case, you need to check with the team still why this private url resolution happened instead of the normal one

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I used `--prefer-offline`

```yaml
- npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline --unsafe-perm --no-optional
```

Removing that option fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to change the content of *.npmrc* file to `package-lock=false`.

Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I added auth token for my artifactory to project's .npmrc like

//artifactory:_auth={token}

token is base64 of email:artifactoryToken

Answer (score -1):

removing the .npmrc from the root directory worked for me

Answer (score -1):

removing the .npmrc from the root directory worked perfectly for me as well

Answer (score -3):

I noticed this error for a public github repo. Removed the entry `always-auth = true` and was able to proceed.