# npm install error 401 when installing a private repository

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am having some issues with NPM and looking for some guidance. When I run the command `npm i`, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - GET https://URL-HERE - Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.
```

When I run `npm whoami`, I see my npm username. When I run `npm token`, I see a complete list of my tokens (including tokens that should give me permission to install the necessary libraries included in my `package.json` file. In addition, I have removed any `.npmrc` files from the repository that I am trying to build.

I have read through this thread from 2018:
[NPM install resulting in 401 Unauthorized for private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823562/npm-install-resulting-in-401-unauthorized-for-private-repo).
However, I have not had any luck with any of the suggestions. Any additional ideas or things that I should investigate?

Answer (score 7):

I found either a solution or a workaround. The following resource was particularly helpful for me:

- https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry

First, generate an access token on your GitHub account. Then, enter the command `npm login --scope=@OWNER --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`. Enter your standard username, **your GitHub token as your password**, and your email address. Run `npm install` again, and your modules should be installed. Here is the example from the GitHub guide:

```
$ npm login --scope=@OWNER --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com

> Username: USERNAME
> Password: TOKEN
> Email: PUBLIC-EMAIL-ADDRESS
```