# What is the simplest way to share react components between projects?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How can I share components across multiple react projects without having to publish them on a public package manager like NPM?

Comment: I can't post an answer but here it goes - You can use module federation to achieve this - https://medium.com/swlh/webpack-5-module-federation-a-game-changer-to-javascript-architecture-bcdd30e02669
More than hapy to write a proper answer when stackoverflow allows to do so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option 1: You can use npm and use private packages so they're not external facing. There are also artifactories and scoped packages that usually represent company-wide projects that can be public or private. See https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro and https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope.

Option 2: Essentially, you can develop projects with a flattened structure. You can then import various projects and/or components into other projects or folders. This is entirely dependent on your codebase and configuration. With this model though, a lot of times publishing to npm comes fairly naturally since each folder may be its own project with its own package.json.

**Updated:**

Option 3: [Bit](https://bit.dev/) focuses on the composability of components from everything from the little things like a button to the actual view and app itself—each target is its own package. Overall, it's an opinionated, yet customizable framework that can enable quicker development, managed dependencies, and organized code.

Option 4: [RushJS](https://rushjs.io/) is a monorepo manager built by Microsoft that allows for flexibility of different kinds of apps and services utilizing pnpm underneath (as opposed to yarn and npm), which alleviates problems that stem from dependency issues.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Bit](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/quick-start):

Bit is an open-source cli tool for collaborating on isolated components across projects and repositories. Use Bit to distribute discrete components from a design library or a project into a standalone reusable package and utilize it across applications.

Comment: Adding links to a video tutorial + walkthrough with code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vS86xgG3ak&t=217s  / 
https://bit.cloud/blog/how-to-reuse-react-components-across-your-projects-l4pz83f4

Comment: seems like this has a dependency on bit.cloud ? that seems like a pretty major change for most companies. unless i'm missing something

Answer (score 3):

You could also upload them to a private git repo such a Github and then pull them in from there.

Ryanve has a nice example over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28729646/1592783

Answer (score 1):

You could create a repo of shared components and then have your Node.js start script call a shell script to do a git pull from that repo and the move the shared components from that directory to your project's directory. That way, every time you call run 'npm start' you will have the latest version of the shared components loaded into your project