# How do I prevent "npm install" or "npm remove" from deleting my personal package?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

I want to have a `node_modules/my-package/...` environment for one of my libraries.

My `package.json` is [considered valid](http://package-json-validator.com/). I has a name and a version and a few other fields:

```
(this is node-modules/my-paclage/package.json)
{
    "name": "my-package",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    ...
}
```

Then I wanted to add it to the `package-lock.json` file so npm knows about it. If you do not do that, an `npm install ...` or `npm uninstall ...` actually deletes the `my-package` folder I created under `node-modules/...`.

So I decided to add the info in my `package-lock.json`, only I'm not able to make it work. All I added is the version like so:

```
(this is package-lock.json)
...
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "my-package": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    }
    ...
}
....
```

Again, the syntax per se is correct. However, with that entry, when I try to do an `npm install ...` or `npm uninstall ...` it tells me:

> error 404 Not Found: krypton-search@1.0.0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did u added into the package info into package-lock.json?

Comment: That's what I show here, in the `"dependencies": { ... "my-package": { "version": "1.0.0" } ... }`. I updated my question to better show that's inside there.

Comment: Why you can't create a new package and install it in usual way? You can install it from github, without publishing to npm.

Comment: @alexmac It's a private package which is why it can't be on those websites.

Answer (score 5):

NPM manages everything under `node_modules/`.  You don't want to add anything there manually.

NPM also manages `package-lock.json`.  It's not intended for you to modify.

To install your package, `my-package`, you want to use `npm install`.  It will copy or symlink your package to `node_modules/`, and will write out the installed version to `package-lock.json`.

If your package is local and not published to NPM, you can use `npm install /path-to-mypackage`.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8089029/362536

Comment: Okay! Excellent! That worked like a charm. It just wasn't self explanatory.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Also, if you have a private Git repo (doesn't have to be GitHub), you can add it as a dependency as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28729646/362536  Use `git+ssh://` if hosted over SSH, or just the path for a local Git repo.