# How to create an NPM package installing directly from a private TFS Repo

Tags: windows, git, npm, tfs, npm-install

I've created an NPM Package on TFS (because my organisation uses TFS instead of normal git/gitbucket/gitlab), that I want to install to other projects.

On Github all I needed to do this was:

```
$ npm install git.com/username/privateRepoName
```

but when I try:

```
$ npm install tfs.organisationname.net/reponame
```

I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code E401
>
> npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be
> invalid.

I've tried multiple methods for hours now on adding my credentials (yes, my windows credentials are the same as my TFS credentials) but i'm not seeming to win nor find the answer anywhere as every example is using git credentials and not TFS.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to tackle this since I have the rights to the TFS repository was to clone it then link it.

First `$ git clone tfs.foo.com/repo` into the project directory then read [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) doc.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install xxx` can be seen as a shorthand for modifying `package.json`, where dependencies can be precised in four ways, as per [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies):

- version range: `"foo": "^1.0.0"`
- URL: `"foo": "https://url.to/the/tarball/of/foo"`
- git URL: `"foo": "https://url.to/foo.git"`
- github: `"foo": "github-username/foo"`
- local path: `"foo": "file:./path/to/the/foo/package"`

NPM has built-ins for [using private git repos as dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728665/how-to-use-private-github-repo-as-npm-dependency), but nothing for TLS.

Luckily, it provides a local path installation which will save you. Simply get the package locally, which you're able to do, make it a local dependency, and you're good to go.