# How to import a component outside root path in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, components, git-submodules

I am having two react applications,

> **Project A**
>
> **Project B**

Here `Project A` is nothing but a simple components application and it contains the only common components.

```
-> src
    -> components
       -> Button
```

This is a very simple button component I have in the `Project A`.

Now the requirement is that I am in the need to use this common button component inside any other react applications.

Here in this scenario, I need to use Button component from `Project A` inside `Project B`.

For which I tried some relative import (I understand it is completely wrong) inside `src/App.js` file of `Project B`  like,

```
import {Button} from "../../../Project A/src/components
```

But it gives the error as expected,

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../Project A/src/components which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

So could anyone help me how to include the button component from `Project A` inside `Project B` ?

**Note:**

I cannot do copy paste of code and also strictly I need to import it from `project` to `project` only.

Also both the projects lies under a single folder like,

```
->Folder
  -> Project A
  -> Project B
```

Comment: For the same scenario, i would publish a package to npm and use that to different projects. Or just copy paste the component. I guess they don't deal with the same data.

Comment: @SifatHaque, I cannot do copy paste.. If doing so then I might not post this question itself.. But this is not something to publish in npm and use it, instead I need to import only from ```One Project``` to ```Another Project``` ..

Answer (score 3):

Since privacy is an issue, I would suggest developing it as a library and instead of publishing it to npm, you can just include it in your `package.json` with a git path. This way, you can push your lib to a private git repo and keep everything in sync.

**Step 1**

Create a new project (e.g. project C) with a new git repository. The setup should be like a npm package, but you will never publish it to npm. It's just for importing.

[Here is a tutorial on what to da](https://medium.com/recraftrelic/building-a-react-component-as-a-npm-module-18308d4ccde9)

**Step 2**

Move all components you want to share from project A in the shared project C. Push to you private git repo to "publish" all changes.

**Step 3**

Adjust the `package.json` from project A and project B to include the new project C, so both can use the shared components.

e.g. `"package-name": "git+ssh://git@myorganisation.com:<user>/shared-project-c.git"` [git+ssh explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728665/how-to-use-private-github-repo-as-npm-dependency/28729646#28729646)

After `npm install` / `yarn install`, you can use your components like any other library.

```js
import {MySharedButton} from "my-shared-project-c"

<MySharedButton... />
```

Comment: Couldn't get your point, developing it as a library mean I should push the code of ```Project A``` to separate github repo and use that github repo inside ```Project B``` - ```package.json``` file?

Comment: You should include it in both projects. I expect you to need it in project A as well, since it is already in this project.

Comment: It is basically a repo with all shared components, something like you would do in a big mono repo.

Comment: I need to include atleast Button component (Even though I have more components like navbar, loader etc..,) from ```Project A``` inside ```Project B``` this is my requirement.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this so I have not worked in mono repos before..

Comment: Extract all components you need in both projects to this new repo and include it in both projects. Whenever you need to include a new component in project B as well, extract it to the shared lib. This way, both projects will have these components.

Comment: For more info, I have a separate git repos for ```Project A``` and ```Project B``` ..

Comment: Don't worry, this is not a monorepo. I just wanted to make a comparison.

Comment: Martin, Could you please update the solution with steps I need to do because I am sorry that I am not getting your point exactly may be because I am new to this..

Comment: Done, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But creating of git repos I am having restrictions, For ```Project A``` and ```Project B``` only I have permissions.. Reason is I am going to only include ```Project A``` button component inside ```Project B``` application.. So why here need to create another repo as ```Project C``` ? I don't think my client will provide me any extra repos other than ```Project A``` and ```Porject B``` ..

Comment: But you need some kind of sharing. In a monorepo, everything would be in ONE git repo, where you have 3 sub-folders. `project A`, `project B` and `shared`. BUt since you have 2 git repos, you need a consistent way to keep them in sync. So doing relative imports won't work, since you can not expect it to work when you just clone `project A` (therefore git). So when you can not create a new git repo, you will have to make it a monorepo (all in one git repo), but then you can never check out only one project without the other one.

Comment: Whether you are saying to copy paste the code from ```Project A``` and ```Project B``` to ```Project C``` ? If I don't have ```Project C``` git repo then what should I need to do? Apologies if I am misunderstanding your comment because I am really not getting the point.. Still I have only this in my mind that I have two project ```Project A``` with button component and ```Project B``` to include a button component from ```Project A``` under ```App.js``` file.. This is my requirement now...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create reusable component across a projects.
you can create reusable component using Bit.dev

Find out from below url for more details:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-share-and-reuse-react-components-6d80e2fd16cd