# Pushing custom node_module while deploying on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-modules

I am trying to deploy my `node-express` website on heroku.  Everything works fine, but just one problem.

I have used express-stormpath as a dependency in my project, which i have customized(the views only).

When I deploy this to heroku, using `git push heroku master`, the node_module is ignored while uploading and all the modules are installed by heroku itself using npm. So my customization to the node module is not reflected at heroku.

I have tried this also: [npm install private github repositories by dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210437/npm-install-private-github-repositories-by-dependency-in-package-json)

Any suggestions on how to upload whole project including the node_modules to heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using express-stormpath, you *should not* be customizing the views inside of node_modules -- this is the wrong way to do it. Instead you should be putting your custom views inside of your own 'views' folder, and telling express-stormpath where that file is.

Here's an example of a custom login view, for instance:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  loginView: __dirname + '/views/login.jade',
  // ...
}));
```

If you take a look at the express-stormpath docs here: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/product.html#update-template-paths (it shows you how to do this).

**NOTE**: I'm the author of express-stormpath and I randomly saw this question ^^ Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Ok.. Thats something true.. But still if using any customized module?

Comment: Just curious because i need to customize few other modules as well.

Comment: If you need to customize another model you should creeate a local module (don't put it in node_modules), put it on a web server, and have npm install it via tarball directly.

Comment: This is the correct answer. node_modules is a generated directory (generated by npm install). You should not modify it by hand (your modifications will just get destroyed).