# Install NPM package as Git clone

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm working on a project that is using one of my own libraries as a dependency. I'm still making lots of changes to my library and therefore I want to require my library as a Git clone.

From the NPM Install documentation get the impression that this is possible [1] but when I add my dependency and I run an `npm install` the dependency is added without any of the Git information I require.

```
"dependencies": {
  "mylib": "bitbucket:acme/mylib#dev-master"
},
```

How can I make NPM do a Git clone in my `node_modules` directory rather then just getting the files?

[1] https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26560992/2452467), and modify it for your repo. It works for almost all cases.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, just getting the plain files, not a Git clone.