# Error code 128 when trying to install packages with npm

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am receiving the following error when I try to `npm install jspdf --save`:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: git submodule update -q --init --recursive
npm ERR! error: waitpid for git-submodule failed: No child processes
```

I installed latest version of npm and still the same:

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.9
NPM: 6.9.0
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: delete the npm and npm-cache directories that locate in c:\myUser\AppData\Roaming. Then, execute npm install -g npm.

Comment: Check the link :
[npm install error code 128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021692/npm-install-error-code-128)

Comment: @DhavalPatel I just did it and same issue. This is to install latest version of npm and mine is the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running application as an Administrator (right click-> Run as Administrator), if its Windows.

Comment: It solved my problem. I just opened cmd as Admin and then tried `npm install jspdf --save` and it worked. Thanks!