# React Native Expo: Error installing masked-view

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I am building an app with Expo and I want to detect if a user has internet connection, but I have trouble installing NetInfo. I tried running:
`expo install @react-native-community/netinfo`

but I get an error:

```
[14:32:00] > npm install
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/react-native-community/masked-view.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T13_34_44_927Z-debug.log

[14:34:44] npm exited with non-zero code: 1
[14:34:44] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Meanwhile when I tried installing masked-view, I got:

```
[13:18:20] > npm install
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/react-native-community/masked-view.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T12_21_03_015Z-debug.log

[13:21:03] npm exited with non-zero code: 1
[13:21:03] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Can anyone help me to find the root of this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021692/npm-install-error-code-128

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing [React Native MaskedView](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-masked-view)

```
yarn add @react-native-community/masked-view
```

or

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, simply tried with below command, it works.

```
npm install @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Alternatively:

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view
```