# Unable to upgrade to nodejs 16.x due to git+ssh error

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, npm, ssh

We are having a nodejs repository in our application which is currently using the below versions of the third party packages -

```
nodejs - 12.22.12
npm - 8.15.0
git - 1.8.3.1
```

There are few other external packages being used but may not be relative here(if required to find the issue, can add them later). And, we are trying to upgrade the nodejs version to 16.x (16.17.0 or 16.18.0) version.

We are using another internal repository as one of the dependent libraries inside this project written in `package.json` file like below -

```
"dependencies": {
   "<repository-name>" : "git+ssh://git@<org-repo-hub>/<path-to-repository>"
}
```

**Note:** The `<>` used above, are just for reference.

and the same is created/updated accordingly in `package-lock.json` file as well. After upgradation to nodejs 16.x, when we try to build it from Jenkins CICD pipeline with `npm install` or `npm ci` or `npm i`, we are constantly getting this error -

```
[2022-10-10T18:32:09.295+0530]  + npm i
[2022-10-10T18:32:18.890+0530]  npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
[2022-10-10T18:32:18.890+0530]  npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@<org-repo-hub>/<path-to-repository>
[2022-10-10T18:32:18.890+0530]  npm ERR! git@<org-repo-hub>/<path-to-repository>: Permission denied (publickey).
[2022-10-10T18:32:18.890+0530]  npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[2022-10-10T18:32:18.890+0530]  npm ERR! 
[2022-10-10T18:32:18.890+0530]  npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[2022-10-10T18:32:18.890+0530]  npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

With the ssh link shown in error above `ssh://git@<org-repo-hub>/<path-to-repository>` , we are able to clone the same repository in local with `git clone` command.

Alternatives tried -

1. We have tried with `git::ssh://git@<org-repo-hub>/<path-to-repository>` instead of `git+ssh://git@<org-repo-hub>/<path-to-repository>`, but still no luck.
2. We have tried with https version of the same git link, but got the same permission issue.

On the other hand, the upgrade of nodejs from the available 12.22.12 version to 15.x (15.14.0) is success without any authentication error, keeping other external packages versions and the code used as constant.

We couldn't understand, why are we getting the authentication error only during upgrade to 16.x?

Any help or support or way forward would be really appreciated. Please let me know in case any other information is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your git install in 7 years old. Just upgrade that to start. So many changes, including security fixes (including to ssh component) and command addition/enhancement/optimization which may relate to your permission issue / ssh publickey error. Does the account/pat /key for the ssh step have access repo?

Comment: Same here, with private repositories. And different Node versions give different errors for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73451512/6309), I would set GIT_SSH_COMMAND to `ssh -Tvv`, to compare the `npm i` output with Node 15 and Node 16.

But that means upgrading Git first, from the old 1.8 to at least 2.10 (which [introduced `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309)).

That way, you can understand what is going on during the SSH clone operation.

Comment: I'm using Git v`2.13.2.windows.1` but ssh doesn't seem to recognize the param `-Tvv`...

Comment: I frequently use it on Windows. In a CMD, type `set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -Tvv"` (assuming that you have `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\` in your `%PATH%`). Then, in that same CMD, launch your npm i, for testing. You can replicate that in your Jenkins job, by [defining and injecting that variable in your job](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins)