# Private github repo as dependency is extraneous on npm install

Tags: node.js, git, npm-install, package.json

This is my first time using a private repo as a dependency in another project. I think I am doing it right, but the dependency is not available in the new project after install and is not in node_modules.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210437/npm-install-private-github-repositories-by-dependency-in-package-json) I can see that I am including it in the package.json correctly like:

```
"myPackage": "git+https://github.com/myusername/mygitrepository.git"
```

When I run `npm install` on this package, I see this that it does not have an error, but after this dependency in the list, it is shown with `extraneous(git+https://github.com/myusername/mygitrepository.git)`.

Even though there is the extraneous issue, there is no error, and the dependency is not available or listed in node_modules.

**Update: repo_A package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Backend utility functions",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/user/repo.git"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/user/repo/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/user/repo#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.25",
    "redis": "^2.7.1",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

**Update: repo_B package.json**

```
{
  "name": "main-project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/user/repo.git"
  },
  "author": "someone else",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/user/repo.git",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "2.1.4",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "langs": "1.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.13.1",
    "node-stopwatch": "0.0.1",
    "request": "2.74.0",
    "winston-loggly": "^1.3.1",
    "utils": "user/repo_A.git#master"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  }
}
```

**Update for latest steps**
Here are the steps I am following now to test each possible solution, followed by the output:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

**Output**

```
├─┬ async@2.1.4
│ └── lodash@4.17.4
├─┬ chai@3.5.0
│ ├── assertion-error@1.0.2
│ ├─┬ deep-eql@0.1.3
│ │ └── type-detect@0.1.1
│ └── type-detect@1.0.0
├── util@1.0.0  extraneous (git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo_A.git#commit-ish)
.......
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you specify https then that will be looking for a login user and password I believe, which I don't think it can load automatically.  I would list it simply as "user/repo" and make sure that machine has an ssh key on it that is in github like the setup described in help such as https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#platform-linux and that things are setup so that pulling down that repo does not require user interaction.

EDIT: After testing, I think the issue is that your `name` in the package.json does not match how you have listed it in your main project's dependencies.  In my test, this resulted in the modules being installed but I got the extraneous message.

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought about the https aspect. However, I have also tried "user/repo" and that has had the same end result. It shows this still:

Comment: `extraneous (git+ssh://git@github.com/username/repo.git)`.

Comment: You did not address the rest of my response about ssh keys etc.

Comment: I did not mention that in my comment as ssh keys are set up and not an issue

Comment: extraneous means "packages that are not listed on the parent package's dependencies list" .. is there a parent package?

Comment: This sounds like I am doing something wrong, and maybe my understanding is wrong and solved in a fairly simple fashion. Here is what I am working with:
repo_A is a simple repo with util functions and its own package.json which includes dependencies such as lodash, mongodb etc.

repo_B is a project repo that uses these utility functions. This has many dependencies, including the util repo, which of course is not working.

What would I need to add to repo_A dependency list, if that is the cause of 'extraneous'?

Comment: If its like you say that sounds like maybe they are not using 'extraneous' to mean that. Can you add the package.json of the main project and the package.json of the util repo to the question please.

Comment: Can you update the post with the exact `npm install` command that you ran?

Comment: See the edit at the bottom of my post about the name field.

Comment: So it needs to be named whatever the other repo is? Like: `"repo_A": user/repo_A`

Comment: The dependency in the main project package.json needs to be listed as "project-name" if the "name" field in the util project's package.json is actually "project-name".  That may or may not match with the repo name on github.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I was using a key/pair of `"util": "user/repo_A"` and was getting this problem. When I follow your advice and change that to `"repo_A": "user/repo_A"`, I do not get extraneous anymore and I can see the directory in the node_modules. Thanks so much and sorry for wasting your time with such a stupid mistake.

Comment: No problem glad I could help.