# How do I import cloned React repo into my files for sandboxing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have forked and cloned ReactTraining/react-router and am wondering how I import my clone into another project.

Instead of:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router'
...
```

I want to do this:

```
import { Router } from './projects/react-router/packages/react-router'
...
```

Note, as seen above, all of my projects are under a directory called `projects`.  If I am working in `projects/react-tutorials`, how do I import my `/projects/react-router`?  Also, lets say I've made no changes so far to react-router, therefore it should be the same should it not?

Answer (score 0):

One options is to use the forked package as npm dependency.
Just add the forked library url path to the package.json like so:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-router": "https://github.com/<github-user-name>/react-router.git"
  }
}
```

and then just run: `npm install`.

you can see more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210437/npm-install-private-github-repositories-by-dependency-in-package-json)

and now you can import it