# npm error trying to install git repository

Tags: node.js, git, npm, leaflet

Having followed another SO, I am trying to include the latest version of a git repo (LeafletJS) that has yet to be pushed to npm.

The packages.config snipped:

```
"dependencies": {
 "leaflet": "git+https://{git hub generated token}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.git",
```

then,

```
npm install
```

reports

> npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c
>   core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler
>   (child_process.js:206:12)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit 
>   git+https://{token}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.git
>   resetting remote
>   C:\Users\bob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-https-{token}-x-oauth-basic-
>   github-com-Leaflet-Leaflet-git-b27a5a7d because of error: { Error:
>   Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get
>   remote.origin.url
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler
>   (child_process.js:206:12)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
>
> npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get
>   remote.origin.url' }

Comment: Do you really need to use your GitHub token? Leaflet is a public repo

Comment: @ghybs its a good question, I dont know. was just following what i saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210437/npm-install-private-github-repositories-by-dependency-in-package-json and tried all ways same result

Comment: Can Leaflet be used server side? ....there's this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet, but I can't find any examples of Node.js usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a simple:

`$ npm install --save https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.git`

correctly installs the latest master version from Leaflet repository (i.e. `git+https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.git#66cf6a0ea1df84dfcae441e91a9aa3bd66531030` at time of writing)

That being said, fetching Leaflet from the source repository might not be the best option for your need unfortunately. Indeed, you will not get the `dist` files. And trying to build them from your `node_modules` directory might not work, because the Leaflet build process uses `git-rev-sync`, which needs to be run in a git version controlled folder, which is not the case of your package when fetched through `npm`…

But you can very easily manually download the current master version on this link:

https://leafletjs-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/content/leaflet/master/leaflet.zip

(dev version link at the top of Leaflet [download page](http://leafletjs.com/download.html))

You can also use them through CDN:

```js
<link href="https://leafletjs-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/content/leaflet/master/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://leafletjs-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/content/leaflet/master/leaflet-src.js"></script>
```

(you will not keep that for production, as these files will keep on changing…)

Comment: I was experiencing yesterday really slow github connections (20kbps), wondering if that may have contributed. i will have another try.

Comment: yes that worked. must be the connection. shame leaflet/master breaks a number of 3rd party dependents!