# How to use (environment) variables for a package.json dependency in npm?

Tags: github, npm, environment-variables, npm-install, package.json

In npm, I want to be able to install a package from a private GitHub repo as a dependency through the `git+https` way without having to hardcode the actual `github_username:personal_access_token`, but rather plug them into the dependency string as (environment) variables.

So instead of

`package.json`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "my-private-github-repo": "git+https://<github_username>:<personal_access_token>@github.com/some/package.git",
  ...
}
```

I would like something like this:

`package.json`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "my-private-github-repo": "git+https://${github_username}:${personal_access_token}@github.com/some/package.git",
  ...
}
```

Hardcoding credentials is a major no-no when *applying version control to* `package.json` which I'd like to be able to do.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312033/3776299 … but i'd go with git+ssh (and keys) instead

Answer (score -2):

1. Create `.env` file at the same directory level where `package.json` resides.
2. Mention `PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN=*******************************` into `.env` file
3. Don't forget to add `.env` into `.gitingore` list which will prevent exposing key to outside world while you make git commit to your repo.
4. Now you can add your dependency in `package.json` as below,

```
"dependencies": {
...
  "my-private-github-repo": "git+https://${ENV.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/USER/abcd-repo-3.4.0.git",
  ...
}
```

There are other ways using 'DOTENV' npm package, but it could not do much when we are trying to resolve "Github" package dependency. Above seems to be straight forward solution.

Comment: Doesn't work, interpolation of the token is not executed before npm install. Did you ever test this? Straight forward, but useless.

Comment: it will never work, the order of the code execute between dependencies and main project are different