# How do I update an npm package to the latest commit?

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

Vulnerabilities in the event-stream package as outlined [here](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/116) have meant that I receive the following error when trying to build my application.

> error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/event-stream/-/event-stream-3.3.6.tgz:
>   Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".

After some digging, I realised that the [mongo-cursor-pagination](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/mongo-cursor-pagination) package I use had a dependency on [mongodb-extended-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-extended-json), which in turn depends on the malicious event-stream package.

After some more searching, it became apparent that the maintainers have updated the problematic dependency as shown by [this commit](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/mongo-cursor-pagination/pull/56).

However, the [latest release](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/mongo-cursor-pagination/releases) v7.1.0 is from 28 June 2018 and doesn't include these changes.

Essentially, I would like my code to include the latest commit to mongo-cursor-pagination but I'm unsure how to go about achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

According documentation, you can set link to git repo with commit sh 
like this:

```
git+https://github.com/mixmaxhq/mongo-cursor-pagination.git#40c3f8d
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

[npm install private github repositories by dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210437/npm-install-private-github-repositories-by-dependency-in-package-json)

Answer (score 1):

You can download it directly from github like this:

```
npm install https://github.com/mixmaxhq/mongo-cursor-pagination/tarball/master --save
```

if you ever need to do it again: https://github.com/{USER}/{REPO}/tarball/{BRANCH}

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the branch name in the Git URL instead of the commit hash should cause NPM to take the latest from that branch. For example, to get the latest from master:

`git+https://github.com/mixmaxhq/mongo-cursor-pagination.git#master`

Answer (score 0):

At least from npm version `10.2.3`, you can use the below format to install through `package.json`.

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@package-name": "github:github-org-or-username/github-repo-name#commit-ID",
  }
...
```

Where

`github-org-or-username` is the Organizational Name in Github, or the Username.

`github-repo-name` is the Repository name in Github.

`commit-ID` is the short commit ID which you prefer.

After adding this, you can simply do `npm install` to install the package.