# How to handle duplicate packages from NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, rollup

I have an NPM package I am working on which has a dependency of `react`. I then have a test app which has `react` installed as a dependency. When I import my npm package into the test app, I get the following error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Running `npm ls react` in my test app suggests I might have a duplicate of `react`:

```
test-app@0.1.0 
├─┬ @package-name/react@1.0.0 -> ./../package-name-react
│ ├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2 // <----------------
├─┬ next@12.1.0
│ ├── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ ├─┬ styled-jsx@5.0.0
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └─┬ use-subscription@1.5.1
│   └── react@17.0.2 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
│ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
└── react@17.0.2 // <----------------
```

My package.json for my npm package looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "@package-name/react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && rollup -c"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^20.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.5",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.56.2",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
}
```

When I remove `react` and `react-dom` from `peerDependencies`, the error goes away but causes other issues. It's almost like `peerDependencies` are being installed and rolled up in my package.

My component in my package is very simple at this stage and is like so:

```js
const MyComponent  = ({ 
  children 
}) => {
  const [myValue, setValue] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFlagValue(true)
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  )
};
```

I am then consuming this package in my test app like so:

```js
import { MyComponent } from "package-name/react";

const MyApp = () => {
  <MyComponent>
    <div>Hello world</div>
  </MyComponent>
}
```

Rollup config:

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: 'cjs',
                sourcemap: true,
                name: 'react-ts-lib'
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: 'esm',
                sourcemap: true
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            external(),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
            postcss(),
            terser()
        ],
    },
    {
        input: 'dist/esm/types/index.d.ts',
        output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: "esm" }],
        external: [/\.css$/],
        plugins: [dts()],
    },
]
```

Comment: Using a version range for peer dependencies is best, since there's more chance that it fits the consuming project's dependencies.

Comment: That said, how you are using the code is likely the issue. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated peerDeps too use range like so: `"react": "^16.0.2",` but still the same issues. I agree that it's good practice but not causing the issue here as I am running the same react version on both.

Comment: I have added a code snippet to show how my very simple component in my package looks like and how it is being consumed by my test app. As you can see, there is no logic happening yet and is purely justta state update in a useEffect.

Comment: I'd like to highlight the results of `npm ls react` are showing a duplicate of the react package is installed. I suspect the issue is more to do with peerDeps being installed in my dist or rollup config causing it to bundle peerDeps?

Comment: It's a possibility that React gets bundled with your lib, which duplicate the dependency within your other project. It's hard to tell since we don't have your bundling configuration though.

Comment: Maybe just adding your `rollup.config.js` file to the question would be enough. Something like a missing `external` config could create this issue.

Comment: I have added my rollup config. It should be excluding deps and checking my `./dist` file, I can't see any node modules in there so i think it is working as expected

Comment: I don't see any obvious issue right now, I'd have to try it to debug more in depth, but I unfortunately can't right now. If you were able to repro in something like a code-sandbox (if even possible with that setup), it would help debugging. But don't feel pressure to do so, maybe someone more knowledgeable with rollup and peer deps will come around.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I have created this simple repo with the issue here to make it easy to replicate https://github.com/stretch0/test-app

Comment: I've created an issue on that repo as it seems some code is missing in a directory that appears to be a symlink.

Comment: Have updated, let me know if you have any more issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not clear from the question description, but looking at the repo, I see that the [package is installed locally](https://github.com/stretch0/test-app/blob/903bb23963c629308cb7e46ab8ad5f80c41140c2/my-app/package.json#L15).

> ```json
> "dependencies": {
>   "next": "12.1.0",
>   "react": "17.0.2",
>   "react-dom": "17.0.2",
>   "react-ts-lib": "file:../react-ts-lib"
> },
> ```

Which means that the lib code still resolves `react` using its own `node_modules` (installed locally) rather than the *app* dependencies.

One way to fix this issue could be to setup the lib project with something like [*create-react-library*](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library), which addresses this problem explicitly:

> If you use react-hooks in your project, when you debug your example
> you may run into an exception Invalid Hook Call Warning. This [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14257)
> explains the reason, your lib and example use a different instance,
> one solution is rewrite the `react` path in your example [app] `package.json`
> to `'file:../node_modules/react'` or `'link:../node_modules/react'`.

Note that in your case, you could simply change the path of `react` in the lib's `devDependencies` to point to the app's `react`:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^20.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.5",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.18",
    "react": "file:../my-app/node_modules/react",
```

Or the other way around, depending on what makes the most sense.

---

There are also other ways to do local development of a React library:

- A [yarn monorepo](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/) makes this really easier to deal with by lifting up dependencies to the root.
- [How to link a local react library with a local react project during development?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60149710/1218980)
- [Publish your library to either github or the npm repository](https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-create-and-publish-a-react-component-library-2oe) in order to install it in your app.
  *This looks like the same tutorial you used to scaffold your project.*

Comment: Thanks so much. You are a legend. Such a good answer with so many options as well as going out of your way to pull down the local setup of the sandbox env I setup. Thanks so much!

Comment: It's a pleasure! It's been awhile since I've worked on a React lib setup and we were using a yarn monorepo which makes this way easier to manage.