# Gitlab: able to clone but not pip install directly

Tags: git, ssh, oauth-2.0, pip, gitlab

I have access to a specific (internal) `gitlab` repo which I can clone, (having configured my `ssh` key on the server):

```
git clone git@mygitlabserver:mynamespace/myproject.git
```

However, when trying to directly install via `pip` a specific artifact from a `tag`:

```
pip install git+ssh://mygitlabserver:mynamespace/myproject.git@v0.2.0#egg=myartifact
```

I get a password prompt.

I have also tried the following:

```
pip install git+ssh://atemporaryTOKENofmine@mygitlabserver:mynamespace/myproject.git@v0.2.0#egg=myartifact

pip install git+ssh://oauth2:atemporaryTOKENofmine@mygitlabserver:mynamespace/myproject.git@v0.2.0#egg=myartifact

pip install git+ssh://gitlab-ci-token:atemporaryTOKENofmine@mygitlabserver:mynamespace/myproject.git@v0.2.0#egg=myartifact
```

Any suggestions?

**edit**: [the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase) does not resolve my issue cause it is not the case of a passphrase-protected key, but rather than a wrong url used.

Thanks to @nils-werner for resolving it (check accepted answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing two kinds of URLs:

```
git@mygitlabserver:mynamespace/myproject.git
```

Is equivalent to

```
ssh://git@mygitlabserver/mynamespace/myproject.git
```

whereas you tried (note the missing username and incorrectly used colon)

```
ssh://mygitlabserver:mynamespace/myproject.git
```

This means the correct pip command is

```
pip install git+ssh://git@mygitlabserver/mynamespace/myproject.git@v0.2.0#egg=myartifact
```

Comment: If I may ask, is there a way - command to also do this via access token? (no key pairs used?)

Comment: Just open a new question for that.

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769426/how-to-pip-install-via-gitlab-repo-directly-using-access-token

Comment: Question is gone =(