# Node js exec how to enter the passphrase for public key in terminal when git clone in a single line

Tags: node.js, git, exec, public-key-encryption

I am writing a script in `node.js` to clone a git repository.

```
 const { exec } = require('child_process');
 exec('git clone <path>.git', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if(err){
          return;
        }

        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      });
```

I need to pass the passphrase key in order to clone using the public key. How to pass it in the single line as an argument for `exec('git clone <path>.git'`

Passphrase should pass as a param and it should not be saved

Rather than moving in to 2 steps is it possible to do in a single step?

Comment: [SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase).

Comment: @AbhinavD this is not to save the paraphrase

Comment: Looks related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66892397/3054025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clone a repository I have used the following library

```
    var cmd = require('node-cmd');
    cmd.get(
      `
        git clone <repo-name>
      `,
      function(err, data, stderr){
          console.log(data);
        }
      );
```

And it worked like a charm

Comment: `cmd.get` does not exist anymore; only `cmd.run`, which unfortunately has the same error of not supporting password input (out-of-the-box).

Comment: which version still has "cmd.get"?

Comment: behind the scenes it looks like node-cmd uses child_process, so I don't see how it would make any difference

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `git clone` will not take a passphrase on the command line. But your node script can read command line arguments. Then you should be able to pass the credentials to the git using [node-expect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-expect).

Comment: You're right, it's not being actively maintained. The other alternatives are a) node-expect substitutes from npm, b) expect/shell script wrapper  over git, exec'ed from your node script, c) replace the node script altogether by expect/shell script