# git credential helper not working

Tags: git, credentials, git-bash

I'm trying to save my git password to avoid typing every time.

I am using git bash on windows 10.

git continues to demand a password everytime I hit remote.

(Is git bash why its not working?)

I have tried:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 28800'
```

And:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

and:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

I've tried it in both git bash and cmd, so I guess it's not git bash causing the problem.

Comment: What version of git? Do you use ssh URLs or http URLs for remotes?

Comment: @phd `git version 2.16.2.windows.1` and this repo was cloned with a .git extension... so that is ssh?

Comment: Well, if you don't know your remotes URLs let's see: `git remote -v`.

Comment: @phd It looks like this: `origin  matt@foo.bar:/home/matt/baz.git (fetch)`

Comment: `user@host` are ssh (scp-like, to be precise) URLs, their credentials are not managed by `credential.helper`.

Comment: @phd Is there any way to save the cred with ssh style?  Or should I try using http?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase)

Comment: @phd OK, I added an ssh key... can I force that to take without recloning repo?

Comment: You don't need to reclone, you need to add the public key to your account at the server and verify with `ssh matt@foo.bar` — should login without asking for password.

Comment: @phd Just want to say thanks for taking the time to help me understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, for Windows, the credential helper to use is `manager`:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Second, this only works for HTTPS URLs, not SSH ones (`user@server.com`)

For SSHs, it is either:

- asking for a passphrase because your private SSH key is passphrase-protected.
  If that is the case, check ssh-agent: see "[Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)"
- asking for  matt's password because it does not find your public key on the remote server art `~matt/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  That is what I had learned from @phd's comments above.

Comment: How can I obtain the public key now that I have generated it?

Comment: In ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub