# Connecting to GitHub with SSH to a project located not in my account

Tags: git, github, ssh

I was trying to set ssh key in order NOT to type my username/Token every time I push updates.
I used this manual to set ssh key and added ssh key to my GitHub account:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

But it still asks me about my username/Token.
I figured out that my URL address is HTTPS rather than git@github.com, so I was trying to follow the solution from here:

[SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase?rq=1)

to replace URL using command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

However, because the project repository is locating not in my account (it is located in my company account where I authorized to commit changes), this does not work (cannot see repository). I am not sure how should I rewrite this command to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your confusion.  Let's see if I can straighten myself out.  When you identify yourself to GitHub, you claim to be someone.  That someone that you claim to be either *does* have access to some repository, or *does not* have access to that repository.

(With me so far?)

When you "log in" to GitHub with HTTPS, you provide:

- a user name: this is just a user name, i.e., it's not *secret*, and it identifies who you are; and
- a password (in Ye Olden Dayse anyway): this is just your secret password, and all it does is prove that you are who you say you are.

They've now fancied things up so that instead of a "password" you provide a "PAT", which is still a secret but now has some internal structure that allows you to do fancy things like say that some PATs have lesser authentication value than others.  This also means that if your "password", i.e., PAT, is ever compromised, you still have the truly secret one—the actual password—which you can use to revoke the old PATs and generate new ones.

If you like this system, you can continue to use it, but if you like the ssh system—it's my own preference—then we have a something a bit trickier.  When you "log in" to GitHub with ssh, you provide:

- the fixed user name `git`: it's not secret, but it also *does not identify **you**;* and
- an *ssh key* as generated with `ssh-keygen` or some similar program.

The ssh key is not, and never has been, just a password.  It's full of structure: it says what kind of encryption was used to make it, for instance, so that we know if it's a old very-short RSA key (no longer secure), a fancier longer RSA key (still secure), an ECDSA key, an ed25519 key, etc.  They also come in *pairs:* there is a public key and a private key in each pair.  The *public* key is designed so that you can hand it over to someone else—including GitHub—maybe even in cleartext.  That someone-else that you give this key *to* can send you a "challenge", that they have encrypted; your computer uses your corresponding *private* key to decrypt the "challenge" and respond, proving that you are in fact who you claim to be.

But hang on a moment.  **Who did you claim to be?**  We just said that we're going to claim to be the fixed name `git`.  Well, now we have a slightly dirty trick: these public-and-private key pairs are *unique*.  When you generate your pair, the public key you hand over to GitHub *is unique*.  All they—GitHub—have to do is record *who you are at the time you give them the public key*, which you do by logging in to GitHub with your actual password.

So, here you are, being yourself, on your computer, with your ssh.  You may have generated, say, *three* identity keys.  If only *one of these three* works for accessing the repository you want, you simply present to GitHub the one identity key that *does* work, and not the other two that *don't* work.

The way you do that is ... not with Git at all.  Git doesn't do ssh.  Git runs `ssh`, which does all the ssh work.  So you must check your ssh documentation.<sup>1</sup>  Fortunately, almost all ssh implementations share a lot of commonality, including the idea of `$HOME/.ssh/config` files.  These configuration files let you tell ssh that, if you ask to connect to a host named `hub-id1`, you'd like to use *one* key-pair to connect to the host actually named `github.com`.  If you ask to connect to a host named `hub-id2`, you'd like to use a *different single key-pair* to connect to the host actually named `github.com`.  You can repeat for as many key-pairs as you have, for as many identities as you want to use.

To do this, in your `.ssh/config` file, you'll want these magic lines:

```
Host hub-id1
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_github_1
    User git
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host hub-id2
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_github_2
    User git
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and so on.

The host-name you put on the `Host` line is up to you, but it should match the name you set in your ssh URL:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://hub-id2/path/to/repo.git
```

or:

```
git remote set-url origin hub-id2:path/to/repo.git
```

The `User` line is optional, but if you include it here, you can leave out the `git@` in front of the place where you'd put `git@github.com`, but are now putting `git@hub-id1` and so on.

The `HostName` line is *required:* it's what ssh will look up to get an IP address to connect to GitHub.

The `IdentityFile` line is *required:* it provides the path name to the file(s) in which you've stored the public and/or private key(s).  There is a bit of trickiness here: if you use the ssh *agent*, you can provide just the pathname of the `.pub` file, and you need only the `.pub` file *on* this host if you're logging in to some corporate machine from your laptop and keep your private keys only on your laptop, for instance.  In some cases, however, you must point ssh to the private key file, and have the public key have the same name but with `.pub` added.

The `IdentitiesOnly` line is optional, but advisable: it says *use only the key I listed here*.  If you omit this line, ssh will try *other* keys as well, if the `IdentityFile` keys don't seem to be working.  (You can observe this in action with `ssh -Tv` output: each key that ssh tries, results in a debug line.)

**If you only have one identity on GitHub, you don't need this complication.**  Your one identity on GitHub—you as yourself—will give you access to the repository, or won't, based on what whoever *owns* the repository set up.  But if you have *more than one identity on GitHub*, and are using ssh, this is how you tell your `ssh` commands which identity to *send* to GitHub.

(Note that if you have encrypted access to your private ssh keys with a passphrase, you may have to type your passphrase into ssh, or into your ssh agent.  This is quite independent of all of the above.)

---

<sup>1</sup>On Windows systems, Git *comes with* a replacement ssh,<sup>2</sup> in case your Windows ssh is too ancient to be usable.  Modern Windows comes with a modern ssh, which is usable.  These two different ssh-es may use different file storage.  Be careful about which ssh you're using.  Make sure your Git uses the ssh you want it to use, whichever one that is.  Most other systems are easier to deal with, as they have just one ssh.

<sup>2</sup>This is similar to the way Git-for-Windows usually comes with a usable version of `bash`, because the old CLIs in old Windows systems are unusable (at least by Git).  Neither the included bash, called [git-bash](/questions/tagged/git-bash) for short, nor the included ssh are actually *part of Git*.  They're just packaged together *with* Git for Windows, to make it *usable*.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. I used  git remote set-url origin hub-id2:path/to/repo.git where "hub-id2" is "git@github.com" and it works now.