# SSH asking for passphrase every time I login to Linux Mint (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, linux-mint, oh-my-zsh, ssh-agent

I've set up my SSH keys for use with Git, and I'm using [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) shell with the [ssh-agent](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/ssh-agent) plugin.

It works great **but** I have to enter the passphrase every time I login.

All the solutions I've seen are geared up for Apple, using `ssh-add -K` to `.zshrc` or editing `~/.ssh/config`.

I have tried using [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140075/ssh-add-is-not-persistent-between-reboots#answer-672680) for editing `ssh/config` but simply can't get it to work :( This is what I have in my config file:

```
Host github.com
  User git
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And apparently [keychain](https://github.com/funtoo/keychain) isn't designed to persist the passphrase:

> With keychain, you only need to enter a passphrase once every time your local machine is rebooted.

Is there any way to do this for an Ubuntu-based Linux?

Comment: People are probably thinking "but this question has been answered a thousand times on Stack Overflow already!" Nope, not as far as I can find, nothing about persisting the passphrase between logins on Linux :)

Comment: Probably because it's not a programming question. This should be asked on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ahh, I thought Stack Overflow was software development as well, git stuff coming under that heading, and I've seen a lot of SSH stuff here eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase Is it best if I move it?

Comment: There are a lot of off-topic questions on Stack Overflow. SSH is not primarily (or even usually) used for software development.

Comment: That's not true, software development relies on version control, which is mostly git, and mostly carried out over SSH! And SSH isn't unix specific, so where should the question be asked?