# why does github ask me for a username and password?

Tags: git, github

I have set up an ssh key but github still asks me for a username and password when I push.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ssh+asks+password

Comment: Esp. the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095345/7976758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are primary 2 ways you can clone a Github Repository **SSH** or **Https**.

If you have cloned your repository with Https method after adding SSH key it will ask you username and password.

To check which version you are using you can run **"git remote -v"**.

If the resposne is having url with "https". You have to update your origin.
Please follow steps mentioned in [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#switching-remote-urls-from-ssh-to-https).

Comment: Thank you sir, you are a hero