# keys not working with smartgit in linux

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu-12.04, ssh-keys, smartgit

I have a git server hosted on ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I am trying to setup ssh key based login with this server which works fine with windows users but fails with linux system using smartgit.

For windows users, I created keys on server, copied them securely on the same server and then using putty-keygen i converted them into ppk and it works fine. However when i create keys for linux users and pass it to the users it doesn't work with smartgit in linux.

Here i have tried both the keys .pem and .ppk but nothing works.

Everytime there is only one error "only private key files with openssh format are supported"

Any suggestion would be a great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8788813/241453

Comment: Please mark this as resolved. I messed up with some things which caused   me a error. Thanks