# Smartgit - cannot connect to repository while on a MAC

Tags: windows, macos, git, github, smartgit

I am trying to connect using SmartGit 6.5.5 (build #4184) to a GitHub private organization repository.  However, on Mac OS X, it's not working.

On SmartGit, I go to Repository -> Clone, then in "Remote Git or SVN Repository" I type in the following address:

https://github.com/JBCJBCJBC/Testing.git"

It does not work on my Mac OS X.  I get the error:

```
"Could not connect to the repository https://github.com/JBCJBCJBC/Testing.git".
Please check the repository URL.  repository "
https://github.com/JBCJBCJBC/Testing" not found: remote: Repository not found"
```

When I downloaded SmartGit for windows on Parallels, and used  the above link, it worked.

Back on OS X, when I use my public folder, it works:
https://github.com/yanjbc/test.git

It seems to have to do with Mac OS X on a private repository that is not working. Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an authentication problem. Instead of revealing information about private repositories, GitHub is (possibly) mimicking the behaviour of a non existent repository.

Can you try this command from the command line?

```
> git ls-remote https://github.com/JBCJBCJBC/Testing.git
12641062c10c8ada29e44c94be905a027a469f00    HEAD
12641062c10c8ada29e44c94be905a027a469f00    refs/heads/master
```

If you do not get any output from the command above, then your authentication settings are not correct, and you will not be able to access the private repository. GitHub has a [guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) on how to setup and troubleshoot key issues.

However, if this gives you some output like the sample above, then you can definitely connect to your private repository in some way. It might mean your issue is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788813/smartgit-wont-authenticate-with-ssh?rq=1) about SmartGit. It seems that answer is related to Windows, so I am not sure how you would proceed on Mac OS X as Putty is a Windows only program.

A couple of alternatives to SmartGit (if you can't get it working with your keys) are:

1. [SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree) from Atlassian (free, but need to register)
2. The good old command line

Comment: Thanks acanby. Appreciate your detailed feedback!  I am switching over to sourcetree based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having weird SmartGit and Firefox behavior on OSX 10.12.4 too. It works perfectly under Linux though.

Answer (score 0):

For Authorized OAuth Apps you may need to grant the organization access.
[github application settings](https://github.com/settings/applications)

Choose SmartGit application and explicitly grant the org.