# Can I use GitHub's 2-Factor Authentication with TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

We like TortoiseGit, and want to take advantage of [GitHub's 2-Factor Authentication](https://help.github.com/categories/84/articles)...but the two don't seem to want to work together.

Comment: The way this is usually handled is that a special app-specific password is generated, so that the app can still access your account, even if it's protected by 2-Factor Auth. Google does this, for example. I'm not sure if GitHub provides this though, I didn't see anything about it in their [2-Factor Auth documentation](https://help.github.com/categories/84/articles).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [GitHub blog post about 2-Factor Authentication](https://github.com/blog/1614-two-factor-authentication) mentions that you can generate a "personal access token", that can be used in place of a password when 2-Factor Auth is enabled:

[image]

I'm not sure if it will actually work with TortoiseGit, but maybe you can give it a try? You can generate an access token at the [Authorized applications settings page](https://github.com/settings/applications):

[image]

Comment: Indeed thanks. The point is that we're looking for a way to use 2FA with Tortoise Git.

Answer (score 39):

To compliment [Cupcake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21892657/456814), use the Personal Access token feature within GitHub.com while using TortoiseGit:

1. [Set up 2-step auth](https://github.com/settings/two_factor_authentication/configure).
2. [Set up a personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) - taking note of the generated token (use the Copy to clipboard button next to the generated token).
3. Set TortoiseGit to remember your password [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351702).
4. Now perform a pull operation on GitHub.com, enter your username, but instead of using your normal password, use the token that was generated in step #2.
5. Perform another pull operation on GitHub.com to ensure the token is remembered.

Comment: Not sure how this question wasn't accepted. The accepted answer is essentially saying "I'm not sure, try it" and linking to a blog page that the OP most likely read (which prompted the question)

Answer (score 10):

Once you create a Personal Access Token in github (see: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), go to your TortoiseGit settings for your repository, then go to the local config like so:

[image]

After that, edit the URL to the repository, in the format of github username:access_token@rest/of/the/url.git, like so:

[image]

Worked for me.  Was able to push code with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone has the same problem - using access tokens with TortoiseGit works in general, though for some reason I couldn't force it to use normal authentication prompt, so I had to do `git clone https://ghusername:accesstoken@github.com/repo.git`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be around for a while and thanks to "Pawel Gorczynski's" answer above I managed to get this to work.

In a specific repository open the '~/repo/.git/config' file and create a line as follows:

`[credential "https://GHUserName:GHPersonalAccessToken@github.com/GHUserName/GHRepository"]`

GHUserName = Your user name on GitHub not your email.
GHPersonalAccessToken = The entire token string generated at https://github.com/settings/tokens
GHRepository = Name of the repository this access token was made for, note '.git' has been excluded.

You can find or create the config file within '~/repo/.git/config' the config file has no extension and should already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to generate access token to pull/push code in Github having two factor authentication using tortoise . Use this token as password.

Here are the additional steps –

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page change