# remote: Invalid username or password, fatal: Authentication failed for

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I have just clone repo an then make one commit add it and was trying to push it - but have this error: [image]

Any ideas how can I fix this evill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to push to https://github.com/AntonDerenivsky/lado, you should use the credentials of AntonDerenivsky.

Using '`fresa`' would only work if `fresa` has been [declared as collaborator](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository) for  `AntonDerenivsky/lado` repo.

Or you need to **[fork that repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)**, and use:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin  https://fresa@github.com/fresa/lado
git push -u origin master
```

If AntonDerenivsky is your gitHub account, the the login to use is 'AntonDerenivsky', not 'fresa'.

Comment: resa@tkd:~/localgit/lado$ git remote rename origin upstream
fresa@tkd:~/localgit/lado$ git remote set-url origin  https://fresa@github.com/fresa/lado
fatal: No such remote 'origin'
fresa@tkd:~/localgit/lado$ git push -u origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fresa@tkd:~/localgit/lado$ 


tryed to fork

Comment: @Rahil I meant `git remote add`, not '`set-url`'. and that supposes you have forked the repo first on GitHub (https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo).

Comment: how can I use my credentials) I'm not strong in git

Comment: I was created lado repo and after that reinstal ubuntu - and now can't connect to it

Comment: Did you fork the repo? Do you have a github account? What error message do you see now?

Comment: yes i did. AntonDerenivsy - my account , i'ts still shows me remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/AntonDerenivsky/lado.git/'

Comment: @Rahil then what is your GitHub account?

Comment: @Rahil then you need to enter AntonDerenivsky as your login, not 'fresa'

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with my first GitHub repository just now. In my case, the problem was related to having enabled two-factor authentication. I had GitHub make an authentication token since the command line tools aren't aware of two-factor authentication.

The problem was that double-clicking the token to select it somehow selected a space to its left as well, resulting in me copying an invalid code. Carefully click-dragging from one end of the token to the other worked.

Comment: For anyone else having trouble with multi-factor authentication on Github and logging in with git read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892226/can-i-use-githubs-2-factor-authentication-with-tortoisegit

Answer (score 6):

If you have changed your password, you can use

```
git remote show origin
```

This will prompt for a username and password wherein you can enter your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding two factor authentication - after re-enabling 2fa I had to delete and re-add the remote endpoint for git to successfully pull.

```
# ERROR: Repository not found.
# fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
# copy and paste ssh destination git@github.com:user/repo.git

git remote -v 
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

Comment: git push --set-upstream origin master

Answer (score 0):

maybe you change your password.
I has the same problem,then  use  upstairs method works.
Remember to replace url `git@github.com:user/repo.git` by yourself.

```
git remote -v 
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
```