# Git Clone - Repository not found

Tags: git, github

```
git clone <url>
```

gives the message fatal: repository 'url' not found

I tried the options in the [link](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found), but it didn't work.

Comment: surely your url must be invalid..

Comment: is it a private repo or a public one? - If it is, try and use the HTTPS address instead of the GIT one. (I hope that you are not doing what @JohnZwinck said...)

Comment: If the repo is public, could you edit your question to add the corresponding url?

Comment: Hi Jubos, its a private repo and i do have the access to that repo.

Comment: I faced a similar situation.  The URL I used for my private repository was correct.  But I was getting the same error.  After much digging I found that in the keychain (I am using Mac Yosemite), entry for the github.com had the old password for github.  I deleted the entry from the keychain then I ran the git clone command.  It asked my github username/password and wallah the clone worked!

Comment: Also make sure that your token has correct scopes - https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps

Comment: The URL should end with a ".git"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are using two factor authorization (2FA) for your Github account then just use SSH option for cloning your repository:

[image]

Answer (score 503):

As mentioned by others the error may occur if the url is wrong.

However, *the error may also occur* if the repo is a private repo and you do not have access or wrong credentials.

Instead of

`git clone https://github.com/REPO_NAME/repo.git`

try

`git clone https://username:password@github.com/REPO_NAME/repo.git`

---

You can also use

`git clone https://username@github.com/REPO_NAME/repo.git`

and git will prompt for the password (thanks to leanne for providing this hint in the comments).

Comment: Thanks - that was useful. I've run into this problem on only one of my systems but can't figure out why. Using the 2nd method works, but I am curious why and if I need to keep using this? What would be cause the problem with the first command, but not with the second?

Comment: On Mac OS X you can store username and password in Keychain (e.g. for GitHub). Then you do not need the second command. If you do not have any thing like this, you need the second command.

Comment: I don't know y. I have been facing the same problem and second solution works

Comment: Also, Adding SSH key in your git account's setting will solve the problem

Comment: what if the password has @ in there?

Comment: Is there any variant of the username:password@github.com syntax for private repos that doesn't require entering the password visibly in the CLI?  One would think git would prompt for auth in this case... maybe I'm running into the OSX keychain cached creds problem

Comment: @CCJ, yes: you can enter everything in the command *except* the `:password`, and git will prompt for the password. For example: `git clone https://username@github.com/NAME/repo.git`

Comment: @ChristianFries it would be awesome if you could update your answer to include the non password visible option in Leanne's comment for future readers.

Comment: @JohnPavek: Done.

Comment: Also, if you have 2-Factor authentication enabled you should use an access token instead of the password - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892226/can-i-use-githubs-2-factor-authentication-with-tortoisegit

Comment: In my case, url to private repo was correct but this suggestion helped me, I was able to clone using git clone https://username:password@github.com/NAME/repo.git

Comment: removing ssh key from github, did the job :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. After hours of searching I finally found something that worked for me.

Comment: No longer working:
`Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021`

Comment: git clone "https://username@github.com/NAME/repo.git" work for me, however password authentication was removed, we need to personal token, -> Setting
->Developer setting
-> Personal access tokens
-> token classic .   Next work for me ,  if you use SSO and 2-Factor authentication enabled, also you can configure in the same token.

Answer (score 52):

**If your git repo is private, try this**

```
git clone https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO_NAME>.git
```

Note: If you are using @ symbol in your password, use **'%40'** to instead **'@'**

**else use this**

```
git clone https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO_NAME>.git
```

**----Update:----**

Using a password in clone URL is now deprecated instead use the personal access token like below

Setting -> Developer Settings -> personal access tokens -> generate new token

```
git clone https://<Token>@github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO_NAME>.git
```

Comment: fine way, to do it but can leave to credential-stealing.

Comment: There should be `@` after `<Token>` in the last command.

Comment: on mac, it worked without username,  only "git clone https://<Token>@github.com/<REPO_NAME>.git" is enough

Answer (score 51):

On macOS it's possible that the cached credentials in the Keychain that git is retrieving are wrong.
It can be an outdated password or that it used the wrong credentials.

#### To update the credentials stored in OS X Keychain

Follow the instructions at:

https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

#### If you want to verify this is the problem you can run clone with tracing.

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

Look for the header line "Authorization: Basic BASE64STRING" .
Take the base64 string and decode it to check what username:password was used.

```
$ echo <the key> | base64 --decode
```

Verify it's the right username password you expected to use.

Comment: I try this and it gives me the username/password for my _other_ account. I guess I need to specify user name...

Comment: This GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 is insanely helpful - thanks!

Comment: If you find your username/password is not correct, how to make git use another one?

Comment: macos keychain can store multiple github logins. If you want to specify which one, `username@` to the github url. Example: `https://username@github.com/foo/bar.git` Then macos keychain will use the correct login password.

Answer (score 46):

If you are on Windows, the repository is private, and different or not longer correct credentials were saved once, you won't have access to the repo. You will get the not found error without hinting in the failed-credential-direction. In order to reset the credentials on Windows, open Control Panel (Win+r control), select User Accounts and Credentials Manager or search for *"credential manager"* in Start Menu. Locate the git account in Windows credentials (not Web credentials!) and erase this entry.

After that, cloning will pop up a login dialogue and you will be able to set these again.

Tested this with git-bash as shell

### In other languages

In Start menu search for

- En: "*Credential Manager*"
- NL: "*Referentiebeheer* "
- DE: "*Anmelde Informationsverwaltung*"
- KR: "*자격 증명 관리자*"

Comment: That fixed my windows issue. delete creds and relogin.

Comment: In Korean, "자격 증명 관리자".

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem (`Repository not found`) due to the fact that initially I logged in with an incorrect GitHub account. To fix it:

1. Open Control Panel from the Start menu.
2. Select User Accounts.
3. Select "Manage your credentials" in the left hand menu.
4. Delete any credentials related to Git or GitHub.

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  I have multiple github accounts, so in Windows, sometimes the git credentials are cached for the other account inside of the windows credentials manager.  Clearing away the cached account allows for this issue to be resolved.

Comment: This incorrect account (cached one) may have not permission to view the repository, so Github/Gitlab return a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: 404 instead of UnAuthorized error. This error message is misleading. Thanks for your help. It works for me too :)

Answer (score 26):

Most probably, your URL is not valid.

If it is a http/https URL, you can quickly check, by hammering the URL into a browser. If that does not display anything at all, you know that the URL is invalid.

I assume you are speaking of a remote repository. The URLs should look somewhat like these:

```
https://github.com/user/repo2.git if you're using HTTPS
git@github.com:user/repo2.git if you're using SSH
```

Comment: it is showing properly on browswer but not working when I m taking clone

Answer (score 26):

For me

```
git clone https://username@github.com/name/repo.git
```

worked.

I think this mainly happens because Private repo can't be accessed directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution no longer works...here's the message I got when I tried it: `Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.`

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me, other solutions are saying to input password, which is quite dangerous

Answer (score 25):

I was also having same issue. I was trying to clone the repo which was private and my git installed in osx has keychain which was not allowing me to clone the repo...

I tried

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/NAME/repo.git
```

but it didn't work as my password was containing the field @.

I just ran

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
```

command and press enter and it worked perfectly fine. Actually you need to remove the keychain already stored in the osx.

Answer (score 19):

*What solved my problem, since I was having a "redirect/sign_in URL" or "repository not found" error*

**MacOS Users:**

1. Open spotlight (Command Space)
2. Type keychain (Open keychain access.app)
3. Search for repo domain (GitHub, GitLab, etc)
4. Delete all keys related to this domain
5. Try to clone again (with valid credentials)

Windows users should try similar steps, but Keychain would be Microsoft's Credentials Manager instead or Windows Credentials depending on yours OS version. Make sure to clean both web and windows credentials if that's the case.

Comment: This may have fixed my issue, not entirely sure since it didn't seem to have an effect at first but later without doing other changes it all started to work again.

Comment: if you have two or more keys chain containing name gitlab and you are not able to delete all in one go then try to delete one by one.(delete one at a time and close keychain section and repeat for the next one)

Comment: Using MacOS Big Sur, deleting the github entry on Key Chain solved the issue.

Answer (score 12):

`git clone https://username@github.com/User/Repository.git` will prompt for a password then clone.

Comment: This solution no longer works...here's the message I got when I tried it: `Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.`

Answer (score 10):

On github you can have the main repository and subfolders. Make sure that the URL that you are using is that of the main repository and not that of a folder. The former will succeed and the latter will produce the repository not found error. If you have a doubt you are in a subfolder, navigate up the repository chain till you find a page which actually specified the https URL and use that.

Comment: This was my problem. If you've got the right level then you should see the `Clone or Download` button on the github page for the URL. If it's not there, then you can't clone it.

Answer (score 9):

***Step 1:***
From your Github account, go to **Settings**
[Account Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39FoU.jpg)
Then, **Developer Settings**
[Developer Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqNue.jpg)
Then **Personal Access Token**
[PAT Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyFMM.jpg)
Then, **Generate New Token** (Give your password)
[Generate Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdnfV.jpg)

Now Fillup the form (scope/access permission of the repository) and click Generate token and Copy the generated Token (***Copy and save it, it will be shown for the first time only, otherwise you have to generate it again***), it will be something like *ghp_sFhFsSHhTzMDreGRLjmks4Tzuzgthdvfsrta*[Copy Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snCRr.jpg)

***Step 2:***
Now, copy the resource indicator:[Resource Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BbLT.jpg)

For example: *https://github.com/AnwarXahid/sso-client-java-servlet.git* and it is generated by https://github.com/**YOUR USERNAME**/**YOUR REPO NAME**.git

*Finally*, open terminal/ git bash and add the PAT token before resource indication:
For example: *https://ghp_sFhFsSHhTzMDreGRLjmks4Tzuzgthdvfsrta@github.com/AnwarXahid/sso-client-java-servlet.git*
Basically, it is generated by https://**YOUR TOKEN**@github.com/**YOUR USERNAME**/**YOUR REPO NAME**.git

So, the final command would like this: ***git clone** *https://**YOUR TOKEN**@github.com/**YOUR USERNAME**/**YOUR REPO NAME**.git**

Press **ENTER** and your repo will be cloned to local!

Comment: It would be helpful to explain to which situations your answer applies. E.g. what you described won't help if the URL is simply wrong.

Comment: @JanWilamowski When a Personal Access Token(PAT) is generated, by default GitHub assumes that the token will simply be used for the public repository (As no access option is chosen by default). In this case, if you use this token for cloning a private repository, you must get an error. My solution specifically works for this type of situation.

Comment: this is an excellent explanation  for when trying to access private repos thank you

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because of my old session state of other user remain: Below is quick solution for Windows users,

Open Control Panel from the Start menu
Select User Accounts
Select "Manage your credentials" in the left hand menu
Delete any credentials related to Git or GitHub

Once I did this, it started working for me.

Answer (score 6):

For me the problems occurs because I have my old username/password settings saved for gitlab, so that I need to remove those credentials. I run the following command on my mac:

```
sudo su
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

and do the clone again, enter the username and password. And everything is fine.

Answer (score 5):

This issue started surfacing on my terminal after I [enabled GitHub 2FA](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa).

Now, I face this issue whenever I clone a private repository. This error:

> remote: Repository not found.
>   fatal: repository 'https://github.com/kmario23/repo-name.git/' not found

is so awkward. Of course, I have this repo and I'm the owner of it.

Anyway, it seems the fix is now that we have to enter the GitHub `username` one more time when cloning a private repo. Below is an example:

```
                             add your username
                                |-------|
$ git clone --recursive https://kmario23@github.com/kmario23/repo-name.git
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I used 2 Github accounts.
And the `git-credential` tries to use the wrong password/token.

##### The solution # 1:

- configure the git to use the full path for credential, by using the following command:

```
git config --global credential.usehttppath true
```

Then, You can see the update inside the global git config file `~./gitconfig`.

```
[credential]
    usehttppath = true
```

- Now, when you try `git clone/fetch/...`, the **`Username`** and `Password` will be asked for every repo.
- Now, the right `Password` will be used

##### The solution # 2:

- Make sure the git repo remote URL (inside `repo/.git/config` file) contains your **`Username`**.
  So instead of:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/company-x/project-y.git
```

You can use the following form:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://{Username}@github.com/company-x/project-y.git
```

- Now, the right `Password` will be used

Comment: Your Solution#1 worked like charm. I had to setup multiple github accounts: Personal and company

Answer (score 4):

I'm a devops engineer and this happens with private repositories. Since I manage multiple Github organizations, I have a few different SSH keys. To overcome this `ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` error, you can use

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=git -i ~/.ssh/ssh_key_for_repo"

git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

Answer (score 4):

```
git clone https://<USERNAME>@github.com/<REPONAME>/repo.git
```

This works fine. Password need to provide.

Comment: Never add passwords to git clone command especially if you are using this in a CI / CD pipeline. Always use a ssh authentication and add the SSH key in your git hub account settings. Adding passwords as plain text is highly insecure.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**Step 1:**
Copy the link from the HTTPS

**Step 2:**  in the local repository do

```
git remote rm origin
```

**Step 3:** replace github.com with username.password@github.com in the copied url

**Step 4:**

```
git remote add origin url
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked by removing the [`credential.helper`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) config and cloning the repository again

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git clone https://<repository>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create an empty file named `git-daemon-export-ok` within the repository directory.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication issue: 
I use TortoiseGit GUI tool, I need to tell tortoise the username and password so that it can access to work with Git/GitHub/Gitlab code base.
To tell it,
rt click inside any folder to get TortoiseGit menu. 
Here TortoseGit > Settings Window > Select Credentials in left nav tree 
Enter 
URL:Git url
Helper: Select windows if your windows credentials are same as the ones for Git  or 'manager' if they are different
userName; Git User Name
Save this settings ans try again. You will be prompted for password and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following and it worked on macOS

1. Save the work and restart the system
2. ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cygwin for git and trying to clone a git repository from a network drive you need to add the cygdrive path.

For example if you are cloning a git repo from z:/

`$ git clone /cygdrive/z/[repo].git`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you did login in another account, and that account doesn't have access rights to this repo, if you're using mac os, go to Keychain Access, search for gitlab.com and remove it and try to git clone again.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have any other github account marked as "default". When trying to clone a new repo, the client (in my case BitBucket) will try to get the credentials that you have set "as default". Just mark your new credentials "as default" and it will allow you to clone the repo, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error, if you are on github, and trying to use deploy keys for multiple repos, you will find this does not work.

In that case you need to create a [machine user](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#machine-users), however if you don't and you try to clone any repo besides the one with the deploy key, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and after quite a bit of debugging I realized that the password that I got from a password generator had an "&" in it, which GitHub accepted, but Visual Studio Code did not like when I tried to clone the reopo. Not sure which system threw the error, but it made me realize that stage characters in your user name or password could also cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in Windows, when I tried to use Git on the command line in Git Bash terminal while having also GitHub desktop installed. So, I did not have any problem using desktop app, but trying to clone in Git Bash failed. There are lots of advice for deleting any previous Git and GitHub related credentials, but this would then mess up GitHub desktop so it is not a good solution if you want to use both GUI and command line methods.
Surprisingly, when I just used Windows command prompt interface (Git CMD) instead of Git Bash, it started working. So, it seems Git Bash has problems co-operating with GitHub desktop configurations, but Windows command prompt works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error today(25/12/2021). The repo was a private repo. I simply installed and configured Github CLI on my machine(running ubuntu 20.04 OS). And it cloned just fine. I push with HTTPS.
Here are some links that will be very helpful:

1. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git
2. https://github.com/cli/cli#installation

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30670823)

Answer (score 0):

***[On the other hand](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-other-hand)***, the problem may have nothing to do with passwords, private repos & all the other solutions offered in the other 30+ answers here:

1. Go to the GitHub repo you want to clone
2. 'Fork' the repo to your GitHub account
3. Now, from your machine's CLI, do the *"usual thing"*:

   ```bash
   $ git clone https://github.com/<your account>/<your fork>
   ```

This is the exact procedure I followed when recently trying to clone some repos at the raspberry pi GitHub site... after spending a considerable amount of time reviewing other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/). It has better error messages.

`gh repo clone <org/repo>`

Answer (score -1):

In my case. repository is private I can't access it directly. On ly way to use Github Desktop app to fetch this repo.

Answer (score -4):

open Credential Manager -> look for your GIT devops profile -> click on it -> edit -> add user and password generated in DevOps and save.

Comment: The OP never stated using DevOps.