# Git Clone ERROR: Repository not found

Tags: git, github

is given the below message fatal: repository 'url' not found

```
Saurabh-Saurabh:~ TestName$ git clone https://github.com/Test/TestNewApp.git
Cloning into 'TestNewApp'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Test/TestNewApp.git/' not found
Saurabh-Saurabh:~ TestName$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Clone - Repository not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947059/git-clone-repository-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Paste the github url in the browser and check . There is no such repository.

Comment: in my case repository is availabel

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting this error is because of the url you have provided as an argument to git clone command. It's not a valid URL. I'm assuming that your username on github is 'test'. You need to provide a correct url to git clone command. In your test repository you'd see a download or clone button : [image: Clone URL]

You need to copy that URL and provide that to git clone as an argument.