# Repository not found, Unable to push to private repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

I get this error when I try to push it to a repo.

```
git push origin master
```

> remote: Repository not found.
>
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/projectname.git/' not found

The url works.

Comment: Can you access to the github repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Clone - Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947059/git-clone-repository-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

check remote repo :

```
git remote -v
```

if there is not repository then add it :

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repositoryName
```

pull the repository :

```
git pull
```

git add and commit by :

```
git add .
git commit -m "your message here"
```

push to repository :

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: I'm not sure these steps will help resolve the issue as the OP has shown that a remote url exists. The issue seems to be whether or not the remote repo exists and the OP has access to it.