# Git repository Error Repository not found

Tags: git, github

Windows 10 , log

```sh
git.exe clone --progress -v "https://github.com/atul****/nodejs-express-mysql.git" "H:\sts\Git\nodejs-express-mysql"
Cloning into 'H:\sts\Git\nodejs-express-mysql'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/atul*****/jenkinsDemo1.git/' not found
```

Comment: Why do you clone "nodejs-express-mysql.git" but your error message shows "jenkinsDemo1.git"?

Comment: Check this out it may help you link ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49594650/9999191)

Comment: @knittl that is the issue why this repo are showing "jenkinsDemo1.git" , already delated this repo.

Answer (score 1):

> that is the issue why this repo are showing "jenkinsDemo1.git" , already delated this repo

Make sure tha new repository is accessible:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/atul****/nodejs-express-mysql.git
```

Check your global configuration:

```
git config --global -l
```

If you see any `insteadOf` directive, that could explain why a github.com URL gets changed automatically