# TortoiseGIT - wincred not available

Tags: git, installation, credentials, tortoisegit

[image: No wincred.]

I have just installed a fresh copy of TortoiseGIT 1.8.7.0 Stable version for 32-bit. I just noticed this problem when I'm setting up password caching for GitHub. Does anyone know how should I fix this?

I do know credential helpers are supported for Git 1.7.10 and up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after Googling around, I found the answer. Ironic though, it's a SO answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14000482/1016891

Step by step:

- Download the wincred extension from the following link:

https://github.com/downloads/msysgit/git/git-credential-wincred.zip

- Extract and place the git extension in the following file location:

(32-bit) C:\Program Files\Git\libexec\git-core

(64-bit) C:\Program Files (x86)\libexec\git-core

Note that the following locations may vary across different installations. Modify the file locations accordingly.

- Right click anywhere, select TortoiseGIT > Settings > Git > Credentials.
- In the drop-down menu, check to see if wincred is loaded. To check, there should be three wincred options available.
- If they exist, wincred is installed correctly. Therefore, TortoiseGIT is now able to use wincred.

Answer (score 0):

Now msysgit 1.9.2 is out.
Please upgrade msysgit.

Then the credential helper will be available for choose in TortoiseGit

Comment: Just to make sure, msysgit is not bundled with TortoiseGit installation? And there won't be any plans to have msysgit be bundled together with TortoiseGit in the future?

Comment: There are internal plans to bundle msysgit. And there is an open issue for discussion (http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=614)

Comment: Well, that discussion ended abruptly. And I don't think that the internal plans to bundle msysgit is still on their TODO list, but rather, due to how TortoiseGit and msysgit are both different in structure (former: WIX, latter: MSI), and the fact that msysgit isn't signed/verified, it makes it harder to bundle them together per TortoiseGit stable releases/updates. From what I can tell, I don't think this is going to happen soon.