# Remove saved credentials from TortoiseGit

Tags: git, credentials, tortoisegit

My credentials are saved in TortoiseGit (using Wincred) but my password changed.
The only way for me to pull from the repository now is to remove the Credential Helper.

How can I simply change the password?
Alternately, can I remove my credentials and save my new ones?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Normally the invalid credentials should be purged automatically (after one unsuccessful authentication attempt).

Go to the Windows `Credential Manager` (press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type "Credential Manager", or go to `Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\Credential Manager` or use Start->Run `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr`; with latest TortoiseGit there also is a button on TortoiseGIt Settings->Git->Credentials), there all saved credentials should be listed (prefixed with `git:`).

For ways to also remove saved credentials on other OS, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944557/3906760.

Comment: Still relevant to this day. The Git and TortoiseGit team should really just include this info in their FAQs directly without linking here.

Comment: On Windows 10 it is quite hard to locate the Control Panel (can find it from Settings/Apps since it has a link to the older Add-Remove Programs at its sidebar - that one is hosted at the Control Panel so you can then reach it from there). What worked for me was a 2nd Pull action, it removed the old credentials and used the new password this time fine

Comment: On Windows 10, type Control Panel in the search box next to the Windows icon on the bottom bar.  Select Control Panel app.  When Control Panel is open, type Credential Manager into the Search Control Panel box at top right.  Select Windows Credentials   Click on the down arrow the right of each credential starting with git: and select Remove

Comment: Found an even easier way - just type Credential Manager into the search box on the bottom bar, then carry on as above.

Comment: Thanx! MrTux for saving my day

Comment: GOD!!! Why... why these guys don't just make a simple user/password ? I'm searching for HOURS just to find a way to CHANGE MY PASSWORD. Can't believe....

Answer (score 26):

I changed my Windows password and now GIT would fail with authentication error, and even doing 2 pull in a row with `git pull -v` would not prompt for the new password.

It was really hard to find the Windows credential manager since not only do I have Windows 10, but also it's a French language version.

I finally found on this [page](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/stored-user-names-and-passwords-windows) I could access it by using:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
```

and I double-clicked on the `git:http:` line to enter the right password and I was then able to pull and push to the repository.

I hope this helps someone else.

I'd still like to understand why it's not asking me for the new password anymore - it used to ask for it the first 2 months after I got my Windows 10 PC (I change password every month)

Answer (score 1):

With Azure DevOps, I found it the easiest to perform a remote operation from Visual Studio. It just does everything automatically and TortoiseGit starts to work again.