# TortoiseGit asking password after it was changed

Tags: git, authentication, credentials, tortoisegit

We are using git from TFS server. Access to the git is granted via Active Directory.

As I installed TortoiseGit everything was fine and it never asked my credential. It always used my Windows user data for credential.

In one moment I changed my Windows password. After this TortoiseGit is asking my credential every time. How can I fix this?

I'm using TortoiseGit 1.8.14.0. In Git/Credential selected "wincred - current Windows user". SSH client: TortoiseGitPLink.exe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove saved credentials from TortoiseGit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782090/remove-saved-credentials-from-tortoisegit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid credentials should be purged automatically after one unsuccessful authentication attempt.

To manually reset saved credentials, go to Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\Credential Manager, there all saved credentials should be listed (prefixed with git:).