# How to reset credentials in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, credentials, tortoisegit

This question is specifically about the TortoiseGit Windows client. I have a computer that I no longer use which must now be transferred to another programmer *without formatting*.

Strangely enough, I can't seem to reset TortoiseGit credentials on this machine. There is apparently no credential helper set in the global settings. In fact, the Windows Credential Manager Service on this machine seems to be permanently disabled. I've changed all the local and global configuration settings to avoid mentioning my Git username at all, but still I can push commits from this machine to all my GitHub remotes.

There are some stack overflow questions about setting and saving credentials. I want the exact opposite.

I don't even remember trying to save credentials in this particular computer ever, which is something I rarely do anyway, and I used this computer very little.

Comment: You're asking to _remove_ saved credentials, not _reset_ them.

Answer (score 111):

go to \Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager click on windows credentials and edit the corresponding credentials

Answer (score 15):

Go to Credential Manager> Windows Credential in the system, there we can update the password.

Answer (score 7):

First, Go to Credentials like:

Right click → TortoiseGit → Settings → Git → Credential.

Then:

Select Credential helper: wincred - this repository only / wincred - current Windows user

Answer (score 7):

How to reset the stored passwords depends on the URL style.

For https credentials the username/password can be stored in the Windows credential store (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782090/remove-saved-credentials-from-tortoisegit) on how to reset) or also in the username in the remote repository URL.

For ssh authentication is often done using public key authentification. Here you need to remove the private key from the machine.

Comment: Thanks for that link, but it is for removing credentials, not resetting them. However, you can also reset credentials used in Windows by following the same procedure: open Credential Manager, go to the Windows Credentials tab, select the dropdown arrow next to the credential (`git:` prefix), and select Edit.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Windows 7 when the remote repos admin changed my password.

From the Start Menu, select Git/Git Bash (I suppose Git CMD should work the same).

Navigate (`cd`) to the git branch folder in the Git BASH/CMD shell.

Then type `git pull` ,

A Dialogue box open with user name and password fields.

Enter here and save.